# How to expand content on a page to fill available space in ConTeXt?

Tags: fontsize, context

I have a document like this:

```
\starttext
    \definepapersize[card][height=8.5in,width=11in]
    \setuppapersize[card][letter, landscape]
    \definemakeup[jeopardy][align=middle,headerstate=start]

    \startmakeup[jeopardy]    
        Text
    \stopmakeup
    \startmakeup[jeopardy]    
        More text
    \stopmakeup
    \startmakeup[jeopardy]    
        This has a whole paragraph. There is some more writing. This has lots.
    \stopmakeup
  \stopttext
```

How can I make the text to expand to fill the available space, not including the page margins? E.g. page one with "Text" might expand 2000% to fill the page, but "More text" is larger, so it expands to 1560%. The last page has a whole paragraph, so maybe only expands 550% to fill that text to the maximum size.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366619/adjust-font-size-to-fit-long-words-in-vbox/366689#366689

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\scale[width=\textwidth]{text to be inserted}`. More details in the Wiki:

https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/scale

Btw your example has a typo in `\stoptext`

### EDIT

If you want line breaks, use a `\framed` inside `\scale`

```
\scale[width=\textwidth]{\framed[frame=off,offset=0cm,align=middle,location=middle] {Text \\ to \\ break}}
```

I've added some line to your MWE so you can see it working.

```
\starttext
    \definepapersize[card][height=8.5in,width=11in]
    \setuppapersize[card][letter, landscape]
    \definemakeup[jeopardy][align=middle,headerstate=start]

    \startmakeup[jeopardy]    
        \scale[width=\textwidth]{Text}
    \stopmakeup
    \startmakeup[jeopardy]    
        \scale[width=\textwidth]{More text}
    \stopmakeup
    \startmakeup[jeopardy]    
        \scale[width=\textwidth]{This has a whole paragraph. There is some more writing. This has lots.}
    \stopmakeup
    \startmakeup[jeopardy]
    \scale[width=\textwidth]{\framed[frame=off,offset=0cm,align=middle,location=middle] {I \\ am \\ awesome}}
    \stopmakeup
\stoptext
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This works great! Is there a way to allow it to give text carriage returns? E.g. the text as a whole line is large, but if carriage return allowed, it can fill even larger.

Comment: [\framed](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Framed) and co. do what you want. Examples are given in the Wiki. If you edit your question to be more precise and include examples, I can help you :)

Comment: See my edited answer