# Automatically bisect latex file for debugging

Tags: emacs, debugging

If I have hard to interpret error messages in a latex file, I comment out half of the file, compile, see if it works or not and so on and find the problematic part by successive bisections.

Is there an automatic way to do this? I know it may be tricky to implement, since you have to find safe places for the bisection. However I guess it is solvable in principle, so I want to know if there a solution out there already.

I am working with linux and emacs, so I would prefer a solution respecting this environment.

The question was partially inspired by the emacs package [bug-hunter](https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter), which "*Automatically debug(s) and bisect(s) your init (.emacs) file!*" (see also [here](https://endlessparentheses.com/debug-your-emacs-init-file-with-the-bug-hunter.html)).

**Edit**

Here is a simple example where it seems difficult to me to find the error. In this case I would try bisecting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\errorcontextlines=1000
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{tikz}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Test
\end{question}


\begin{solution}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{solution}


\begin{question}
Test
\end{question}


\begin{solution}
Test
\end{solution}

\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

Output of the log file: https://pastebin.com/kFfWu2zL

Comment: bisecting the first half is easy as you can just put `\end{document}` in the middle and just process half, if you need the second half that's harder and not in general possible as it may require definitions from earlier, although if you assume all definitions in the preamble it is not so bad, emacs auctex lets you preview a marked region (by copying the preamble and the region to a temporary document behind the scenes)

Comment: To remove the first half, you can use `\iffalse first half \fi`, and then successively move done `\fi`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and gernot: Yes, that's clear. What I am looking for is an *automatic* solution.

Comment: you can't literally bisect anywhere: you have to choose safe places so automatic bisection might be tricky, it's not normally needed as the log should normally give fairly accurate indication of the location of the error: you know how many pages are output before the error, and you have the line number of the source error

Comment: I don't know the package, you could give an example, you can always set `\errorcontextlines=1000` and get a full error context.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: See my edit above.

Comment: This is *definitely* not possible, because of how complex TeX is. There's still [compiling - Reducing the console output of LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/reducing-the-console-output-of-latex) --

Comment: For me it gives `Undefined control sequence.` // `<argument> Test \myerror` so that makes quite clear where the error is (search for `\myerror` in the source code)

Comment: @user202729: Yes, I wanted just show an example where you see that it doesn't report a correct line number.

Comment: @user202729: I tried to slightly modify the example. See my edit abvove.

Comment: Your example is actually one were bisecting is of little use. If you drop the first half the error will be gone, and if you drop the second half, the error will be gone too. It is just "delayed content". And the log shows you clearly that the error occurs when `\printsolutions` is called. Line number and all.

Comment: There's *just* no way the (what you think is) correct answer could be printed in the very-general case. TeX is just too powerful. Imagine this...

Comment: In Python (you know some conventional programming language right?) you set `x="myerror()"` in line 10 and `exec(x)` in line 20. How can Python possibly know which line the literal `myerror` appeared in the source code? It will report the error on line 20.

Comment: *maybe* it's possible to tag a file/line number information to *every* token and report that, but it requires significant reimplementation of the engine and (as far as I know) nobody have done that. (and it may not even that useful)

Comment: @gnusbr: In this case I would consider only the part before `\printsolutions` for bisecting. However it is clear, that it is nontrivial to come with an algorithm that automatically does such decisions.

Comment: @user202729: Why does it work in lisp with bug-hunter? Lisp is turing complete too.

Comment: I doubt it works in lisp either, here you are saving tex code unexecuted (with a syntax error) and getting an error at the point you execute it rather than at the point you save it. If you save an s-exprerssion in lisp and then evaluate it later you would similarly get an error at the eval, not at the point that you constructed the erroneous s-expression.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that particular thing, so it would be hard to discuss... (although my guess is [the comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624751/automatically-bisect-latex-file-for-debugging?noredirect=1#comment1559799_624751))

Comment: Okay I took a look at some examples, and there's nothing as complex as the store-verbatim → eval process in TeX in this case. Perhaps you can give some more complex example?

Answer (score 1):

This is an explanation on the particular example, and why it's hard to debug.

---

### What happened to the stack trace?

Because of [tail-call optimization](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/627520/250119), the important error context line is missing.

Compare: if you add `\relax` (or anything nonempty) after the tikzpicture environment in the erroneous, a relevant context line is printed.

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...ackage tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help\@err@                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\GenericError  ...                                                 \@empty \def \MessageBreak  
#1 \def   \errmessage  #2.

#3
Type  H <return>  for immediate help\@err@                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \endgroup 
\pgfutil@next ->\advance \tikz@expandcount by -1 \ifnum \tikz@expandcount <0\relax \tikzerror {Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?}
                                                                                                                                                   \let \pgfutil@next =\tikz@finish \else \let \pgfutil@next =\tikz@@expand \fi \pgfutil@next 
\pgf@let@token ->\tikz@atend@picture \global 
                                             \let \pgf@shift@baseline@smuggle =\pgf@baseline \global \let \pgf@trimleft@final@smuggle =\pgf@trimleft \global \let \pgf@trimright@final@smuggle =\pgf@trimright \global \let \pgf@remember@smuggle =\ifpgfre...
\end  #1->\romannumeral \IfHookEmptyTF {env/#1/end}{\expandafter \z@ }{\z@ \UseHook {env/#1/end}}\csname end#1\endcsname 
                                                                                                                         \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@endpe \@doendpe \fi \UseHook {env/#1/after}\if@ignore \@ignorefalse \ignorespaces \fi 
<argument> \begin {tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) \end {tikzpicture}
                                                             \relax 
\exsheetsprintsolution #1#2->#1#2
                                 
\__exsheets_surround_with:nnn #1#2#3->#2#1
                                          #3
\__exsheets_print_solution:nnn ...tl {#2}{#1}}{\exp_not:V \l__exsheets_solutions_pre_body_hook_tl \exp_not:n {#3}\exp_not:V \l__exsheets_solutions_post_body_hook_tl }}\l__exsheets_solutions_pre_hook_tl \l__exsheets_solutions_post_hook_tl 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \exsheets_add...
\__prop_map_function:Nwwn #1#2\__prop_pair:wn #3\s__prop #4->#2#1{#3}{#4}
                                                                         \__prop_map_function:Nwwn #1
\g_exsheets_question_identification_prop ->\s__prop \__prop_pair:wn 1\s__prop {-0-1}
                                                                                    \__prop_pair:wn 2\s__prop {-0-2}
\prop_map_function:NN #1#2->\exp_after:wN \use_i_ii:nnn \exp_after:wN \__prop_map_function:Nwwn \exp_after:wN #2#1
                                                                                                                  \prg_break: \__prop_pair:wn \s__prop {}\prg_break_point: \prg_break_point:Nn \prop_map_break: {}
\__keys_set_keyval:nnn ...path_str \s__keys_stop \l__keys_module_str \l_keys_key_str \tl_set_eq:NN \l_keys_key_tl \l_keys_key_str \__keys_value_or_default:n {#3}\bool_if:NTF \l__keys_selective_bool \__keys_set_selective: \__keys_execute: 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \str_set:Nn \...
\__keyval_key:nn #1#2->\__keyval_if_blank:w \s__keyval_mark #1\s__keyval_nil \s__keyval_stop \__keyval_blank_key_error:w \s__keyval_mark \s__keyval_stop \exp_not:n {#2{#1}}
                                                                                                                                                                            \__keyval_loop_other:nnw {#2}
\__keyval_loop_other:nnw ..._keyval_if_recursion_tail:w #3\__keyval_end_loop_other:w \s__keyval_tail \__keyval_split_active:w #3\s__keyval_nil \s__keyval_mark \__keyval_split_active_auxi:w =\s__keyval_mark \__keyval_clean_up_active:w {#1}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              {#2}\s__keyva...
\__keyval_loop_active:nnw #1#2#3,->\__keyval_if_recursion_tail:w #3\__keyval_end_loop_active:w \s__keyval_tail \__keyval_loop_other:nnw {#1}{#2}#3,
                                                                                                                                                   \s__keyval_tail ,
\keyval_parse:NNn #1#2#3->\__keyval_loop_active:nnw {#1}{#2}\s__keyval_mark #3,
                                                                               \s__keyval_tail ,
\__keys_set:nnn #1#2#3->\str_set:Nx \l__keys_module_str {\__keys_trim_spaces:n {#2}}\keyval_parse:NNn \__keys_set_keyval:n \__keys_set_keyval:nn {#3}
                                                                                                                                                     \str_set:Nn \l__keys_module_str {#1}
\l__exp_internal_tl ...\l__keys_only_known_bool \bool_set_false:N \l__keys_filtered_bool \bool_set_false:N \l__keys_selective_bool \tl_set:Nn \l__keys_relative_tl {\q__keys_no_value }\__keys_set:nn {exsheets/exsheets_print_solutions}{all}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \tl_set:Nn \l...
\exsheets_print_solutions:n ...exsheets_solutions_print_bool \bool_set_true:N \l__exsheets_inside_solution_bool \cs_set:Npn \S ##1{\exref {exse:##1}}\cs_set:Npn \C ##1{\exref {exch:##1}}\keys_set:nn {exsheets/exsheets_print_solutions}{#1}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              \group_end: 
<to be read again> 
\end 
l.32 \end
       {document}
```

Note the line

```
<argument> \begin {tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) \end {tikzpicture}
                                                             \relax
```

Which is the content you typed in.

### What happened to the line number?

The code you shown in TeX is roughly equivalent to the following (pseudo)code in Python:

```python
# ======== tikz library

def tikzPicture(s: str):
    if ";" not in s: raise RuntimeError("No semicolon")
    return "figure"

# ======== exsheets library

solutions=[]
def addSolution(s: str):
    solutions.append(s)

def printSolutions():
    for solution in solutions: print(eval(solution))

# ======== your code

addSolution("'Test'")
addSolution("tikzPicture('draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1);')")
addSolution("tikzPicture('draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1)')")  # line 21 here

printSolutions()
```

The traceback in Python is

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FILE", line 23, in <module>
    printSolutions()
  File "FILE", line 15, in printSolutions
    for solution in solutions: print(eval(solution))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "FILE", line 5, in tikzPicture
    if ";" not in s: raise RuntimeError("No semicolon")
RuntimeError: No semicolon
```

As you can see, the traceback only point to line 23 (`printSolutions`), not line 21 which is where you actually add the code.

(also note that in TeX the "most recent call" is the first, not the last)

#### Python: could it be better?

In fact Python is even *worse* in this particular example! (it's fixable, see [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183305/file-string-traceback-with-line-preview))

The only reason you don't encounter it in "normal" programming languages is that it's extremely rare for you to use `eval`/`exec`.

What could the theoretical Python library improve?

- On `addSolution`, store the stack content somewhere, then print it back. That way you can get the "line 21".
- On `printSolutions`, when there's the error then *print out the user's source code*.

The obvious disadvantage is the time/memory/code complexity/maintenance difficulty overhead.

#### TeX: could it be better?

Both solutions above applies, requires modifications in the `exsheets` package.

- It's possible to store the current line number when `\begin{solution}` is defined along with the verbatim solution text,
  and print it on execution (somewhere, for example in the log)
- Without that, it remains possible for the package to print out the solution content before rendering each solution.

  ([there's no `try...catch` or `try...except` in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26460/250119))

  For the tail-call optimization case, as mentioned in the linked question above, it's possible to look at the output of
  `\tracingmacros=1` to determine the context.

  For this particular package at this particular version, the omitted "user layer" is right above (more recent than)
  the `exsheetsprintsolution` layer. So search for the last occurrence of `\exsheetsprintsolution` before the traceback
  in the log. In this particular case it is

  ```
  \exsheetsprintsolution #1#2->#1#2

  #1<-\exsheets_solutions_print_name:Vnn \l__exsheets_tmpa_tl {\GetTranslation {exsheets-solution-name}}{1}

  #2<-\begin {tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) \end {tikzpicture}
  ```

  You can clearly see that `#2` is your code.

  Alternatively (reminder: this is *specific to this particular package implementation/version*)
  it's possible to print out the content of your environment (already tokenized)
  by typing `I\ExplSyntaxOn\show\l__exsheets_tmpb_tl` at the TeX error prompt.

##### What happened to the newline?

It's another issue with the `exsheets` package: the content inside the environment is not stored verbatim,
rather it's parsed directly, the parse removes the newlines.

You can easily see that `exsheets` does not store verbatim things correctly:

```
\begin{solution}
    \verb+%+
\end{solution}
```

(not related to this question, but you can use `\cprotEnv` in `cprotect` package to fix the issue.)

##### Why is `\scantokens` (`exec`-equivalent) so common in TeX?

Basically, in order to parse TeX correctly in general case, you have to execute the code.

So when you want to *store the content without executing the code*, you *must* store it in verbatim
(roughly "as a string"), then execute it later as a string.

Although in this particular case, it's collected as an argument. That also destroys the line number.

Comment: A better solution would be redefining `\exsheetsprintsolution` which is part of the "public API" so is less likely to break.