# Can Lua access the traceback/surrounding tokens on error?

Tags: errors, luatex

Let's say if I have...

```
\documentclass{article}
\errorcontextlines=10000
\def\c{1 \errorerror 2}
\def\b{3 \c 4}
\def\a{5 \b 6}
7 \a 8
```

I can

- see the traceback on the console...

  ```
  ! Undefined control sequence.
  \c ->1 \errorerror
                     2
  <argument> 3 \c
       4
  \b #1->7 #1
              8
  \a ->5 \b {3 \c 4}
                     6
  l.13 7 \a
          8
  ```
- run some code when there's error (`show_error_hook` callback)...
- access the string content of the error message `status.lasterrorcontext`, `status.lasterrormessage`
- get the following tokens with repeated calls to `token.get_next()`

However **can I do the following**:

- get the csname of the undefined token (programmatically)? Parsing the error message is not reliable.
- get the surrounding content (e.g. "before is `5 3 1`")?
- get the *actual* macros in the traceback (a, b, c in this case) and where in the definition they're currently at?

For context, sometimes the error message doesn't display nicely on the terminal (which is limited to text output so e.g. cannot distinguish active space from normal space / a [small](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52994/250119) number of columns ), so I want to get the tokens and format it to something nicer.

Comment: `status.lasterrorcontext` ?

Comment: Ah, "the status table" they mention refers to "the status library" (section 10.2). Reading...

Comment: Hm, checked, that get the error text itself, but no more than that. Cannot get the tokens etc.

Comment: yes I think that's right

Comment: Actually token.get_next might work. Testing some more...

Comment: Okay turns out token.get_next works to get **following** tokens (2, etc.) but not **previous** tokens. (`\errorerror` itself)

Comment: status.input_ptr should be pointing at the various recusive input levels but I'm not sure how to use it to be honest

Comment: See, I think the documentation is poor...

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3973372#3973372

Comment: Looks like there was a token_filter callback in Lua although I'm not sure what it's used for. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45293/can-the-lua-part-of-luatex-know-about-tokens?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot get the tokens before the error. TeX almost never looks back at previous tokens (as far as I know `\over` is the only exception).

Comment: @HenriMenke Maybe LuaTeX exposes something for this, but if it doesn't then it's unfortunate.