# Adjust font size on-the-fly

Tags: boxes, fontsize

In my document I want to emphasize some key points by placing them in a box with rounded corners. This I do using the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}

\ovalbox{
\begin{minipage}[c][.35\textwidth]{.5\textwidth} % [text in box][height][width]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.9\textwidth}
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

The dimensions of the box I would like to have fixed. When the text now becomes too big for the box, can I let LateX notice that and have it **adjust the font size** such that it does fit?

I was made aware of this [fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize) question, but have not been able to transform the answer it into a workable solution for me (i.e. getting an `\ovalbox` around it).

Further have I noticed that paragraphs in the proposed solutions are not indented anymore, how can that be avoided?

Comment: Do you want to scale it or re-typeset it with a small font size?

Comment: Doesn't really matter actually. As long as the text fits. What is easier?

Comment: Scaling would be easier, but then you get a different width as well. Repeating the typesetting with a smaller font would give better looking results.

Comment: If found now the question [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize), which seems to be a duplicate. Have a look at it and tell us if it answers your question.

Comment: Imho none will look good: You will get boxes with varying font sizes. Use at most one font size command e.g. `\small` or adjust the height of the boxes.

Comment: BTW: You are missing a `%` behind `\ovalbox{`. As it is now it inserts an extra space there.

Comment: You still need to assign your bounty. This is independent from accepting answers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancybox,environ}

\NewEnviron{textinoval}
  {\def\trysize{10.5pt}\def\tryblskip{12.5pt}%
   \retry}
\makeatletter
\def\retry{%
  \ifdim\trysize<5.5pt
    \WARNING\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\edef\trysize{\the\dimexpr\trysize-0.5pt\relax}%
   \edef\tryblskip{\the\dimexpr\tryblskip-0.5pt\relax}%
   \sbox0{\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
   \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
     \noexpand\fontsize{\trysize}{\tryblskip}\noexpand\selectfont}\x
   \BODY\end{minipage}}%
  }%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
  \ifdim\dimen0>.3\textwidth
    \expandafter\retry
  \else
    \expandafter\outputoval
  \fi}
\makeatletter

\def\WARNING{\sbox{0}{WARNING}}

\def\outputoval{\ovalbox{\begin{minipage}[c][.35\textwidth]{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}\usebox{0}\end{center}\end{minipage}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{textinoval}
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
\end{textinoval}

\begin{textinoval}
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
\end{textinoval}

\begin{textinoval}
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
\end{textinoval}

\begin{textinoval}
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
\end{textinoval}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are some explanations. First of all, the `\NewEnviron`-defined environment gathers its contents. This contents is typeset in a "private" box and if it fits the size requirements it's passed for final typesetting; otherwise we try at a size half a point less and redo until the requirements are respected. One can redefine `\WARNING` as wished; it will be come into action when the recursion is started and the font is already at 5pt size.

Comment: Nice, this solves the fontsize problem. However, it still does not indent the paragraphs inside the minipage|fancybox...

Comment: @D.Roepo: Add `\setlength{\parindent}{1em}\noindent` after `\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}`.

Comment: This works now as I had in mind, sweet. Would you at some point add some comments saying what's going on, then I might learn something. Thanks heaps

Comment: Reminds me on [my answer to a similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize/26004#26004), but your solution seems to work better.

Comment: @egreg You need to check for some limits try `\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum`, works well up to three `\lipsum`, nice solution though, but any optimization problem must specify the constraints clearly:)

Answer (score 7):

For the general case please see [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize). For your specific case you could use the following way, which scales the content if required. I'm not saying that will give nice results in all cases.

Note that the use of `minipage` modifies the `\textwidth` so that length can be different at different places. Keep also in mind that later `adjustbox` keys can effect earlier one because of this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newenvironment{myovalbox}{%
    \noindent
    \adjustbox{minipage=[c]{.45\textwidth},margin=1ex,max totalsize={\textwidth}{.7\textwidth},center=.5\textwidth,
    env={minipage}[c][.35\textwidth]{.5\textwidth},
    precode=\ovalbox}\bgroup
}{%
    \egroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myovalbox}
This text is small enough to fit in the box.
\end{myovalbox}

\begin{myovalbox}
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
\end{myovalbox}

\begin{myovalbox}
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
\end{myovalbox}

\begin{myovalbox}
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
\end{myovalbox}

\begin{myovalbox}
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
This text might be too large to fit into the (.35x.50)$\cdot$textwidth box,
in which case the font size should be decreased to make it fit.
\end{myovalbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You seem to use an old version of `storebox`. Use the one on CTAN or https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/storebox/src/tip/storebox.sty.

Comment: "fotsize stays fied"? You means "fontsize stays fixed", right? But what does "the bi size varies" mean?

Comment: Bluntly copy-pasting your code yield boxes of different sizes in my document. I slightly modified your environment definition, to `\newenvironment{myovalbox}{% 
    \noindent 
    \adjustbox{minipage=[c][.35\textwidth]{.465\textwidth},max totalsize={.4185\textwidth}{.315\textwidth},center=.5\textwidth,
  env={minipage}[c][.35\textwidth]{.465\textwidth}, 
    precode=\ovalbox}\bgroup 
}{% 
    \egroup 
}`. This way the box size stays fixed, but the fontsize is not affected whatsoever, resulting in text outside its box. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but the code works as shown for me with a freshly updated TeX Live 2011. Which LaTeX distribution are you using then?