# How to set size of pdf page in pixels and put a background image

Tags: graphics, margins, backgrounds

I need to create certificates in pdf. I have an image, where the text must be put to the appropriate place. I managed to set the correct pdf page size and all margins, except the top:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[paperwidth=1055px,paperheight=700px]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0px}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{bg.png}
\end{document}
```

But there is little top margin, that shifts the image out of the page.

[image]

How can I set the picture as the background of this page? And remove the margin?

Then I'll use tikz to position the text.

Comment: Related: [Package for certificates](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46406/5764)

Comment: Wouldn't `margin=0pt` among the option to `geometry` help? I would never use `px` as unit: use `bp` if you know the precise dimensions of the image in Postscript points (72bp=1in).

Comment: @egreg 1. "Wouldn't margin=0pt among the option to geometry help?" - I tried it, but it didn't work. Produces margins at the bottom & right of the page. I used oddsidemargin & topmargin. Look at my answer below. 2. "I would never use px as unit" - they gave me a picture and told to create a pdf of the same size & use it as a background. That's why I used px. Is bp better in this case as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,101,0}
\color{green}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{12mm}{11mm}\selectfont
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics{bg.png}};
    \draw (1, 1) node[align=center] {mr. Dummy\\
      Group Name};
    \node at (7.4cm, -3.09cm) {10.01.2013};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Gives this:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I downloaded the PNG of your self answer and did

```
file QXom4.png
```

getting the answer

```
QXom4.png: PNG image data, 600 x 399, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

Then I created the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperheight=399bp,paperwidth=600bp]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{QXom4.png}
\end{document}
```

This produced a PDF file with no margin whatsoever.

However, the simpler

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{QXom4.png}
\end{document}
```

did the same, because `standalone` automatically clips the PDF to the dimension of its contents.

The default value of 1px is equal to 1bp. Well, 1px is 65782 scaled points, while 1bp is 65781 scaled points (1pt = 65536 scaled points, the difference is negligible). It's not recommended to use it (if you don't set it in your document with `\pdfpxdimen`), because it can be changed at format creation.

Comment: I improved my answer, using your suggestions. With standalone the code is much better.

Answer (score 8):

pdftex (and most likely also luatex, also I haven't checked) provides a primitive `\pdfpxdimen` and the unit `px`. See the [pdftex manual](http://sarovar.org/docman/view.php/106/64/pdftex-a.pdf.pdf), section 7.9. An example from the manual:

```
\pdfpxdimen=1in % 1 dpi
\divide\pdfpxdimen by 96 % 96 dpi
\hsize=1200px
```

`px` *should* work with the `geometry` package.

Comment: Yes, I did it with geometry package. But can't remove the top and left margins.

Comment: @user4035: It's not nice to remove parts of your question after somebody answered them. Can I at least get an upvote? :-)

Comment: Sorry, I saw your answer exactly after I saved the edit :).