# Names on certificates

Tags: macros, programming

I have to make some certificates. The main problem is not the certificate itself but to change names between pages. Can I create a list of names, each of appears once for page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes everything is possible as long as TeX is turing complete. But no, we cannot help unless you give us some concrete example. Are you going to draw the certificates by yourself? Any customization (ID, photo, color for grading, etc.) other than names? One PDF file for all certificates or a file for each?

Comment: Hey, we have a certificates question already: [Package for certificates](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46425) and a blog too on this site. Where is that link, I am not able to get it now. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have dozens of names the `datatool` package is probably the best way to go. If it's just a few and you want to avoid the work anyway you can also loop directly in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[45pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=0.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\centering

\foreach \x in {Manfred Mustermann, Gabi Mustermann, Manuela Mustermann}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
[mybox/.style={rectangle,black,xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,minimum width=0.975\textwidth,font=\bfseries,draw=black,very thick,align=center, minimum height=0.475\textheight}]
\node at (0,0) [mybox] {\x};
\node at (0,0.475\textheight) [mybox] {};
\end{tikzpicture}\clearpage}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]