# Paragraph with a colored circle

Tags: color, tikz-styles, paragraphs, circles

I would like to put a red circle before the beginning of a paragraph.

This code does that effect but there are a lot of errors:

```
\paragraph{{\tikz{\draw[red,fill=red] (0,0) circle (.5ex);}} PARAGRAPH}
```

What I have to do in order to avoid errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like marmots, sometimes Ti*k*Z needs a bit of protection. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{\protect\tikz{\fill[red] (0,0) circle (.5ex);} PARAGRAPH}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, for red bullets you do not need Ti*k*Z, you could just load `xcolor` and do `\paragraph{\textcolor{red}{\textbullet} PARAGRAPH}` to achieve virtually the same. I am assuming that you want to do more fancy things.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph, assuming that here  "fancy" mean really "needlessly convoluted" `:)`

Comment: @Fran I was more thinking about [marmots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441716/121799), [bears and penguins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444989/121799), and [koalas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448397/121799). All of them need a bit protection...;-)

Comment: I sympathize with that. Also the snorers readers are endangered because of lack of space in our natural hábitats.

Comment: @Fran That's what I thought (given that you produced such a nice [certificate for marmot students](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73680/121799) ;-)