# How to put different colours in different minipages in overleaf

Tags: color, minipage

I am trying to make a result template in Overleaf. I have split my page into 5 parts using minipages. The upper half of my page has 3 minipages which allow me to have a text in between 2 images and I want it to have black background colour. While the lower half of my page is split into 2 minipages and I want them to have grey background colour. How can I do it?
When I try `\pagecolor{black}\color{white}` it makes the entire page black.

**Thanks to Fran for solving my issue above. But, now I'm stuck with their alignment.**

Here's my current code:-

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{parskip}


\begin{document}
\pagecolor{gray!30}
\sffamily\bfseries
\fboxsep0.8cm
\colorbox{black}{\color{white}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=.1\linewidth]{Zaariya.png}\hfil  
\parbox[c]{.75\linewidth}{\centering\Huge Sci\textcolor{red}{Q}uest 2\textcolor{red}{K}20 \par}\hfil  
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=.1\linewidth]{Niser_logo.png}
\end{minipage}}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
\Large \textbf{Name:-} <<Students Name>>\\
\textbf{Class:-} <<His Class>>\\\vspace{1.2cm}
\textbf{Roll No:-} <<ROLL>> \\
\textbf{Marks:-}\\
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Subject 1 :} <<Marks1>>
    \item \textbf{Subject 2 :} <<Marks2>>
    \item \textbf{Subject 3 :} <<Marks3>>
    \item \textbf{Subject 4 :} <<Marks4>>
    \item \textbf{Total :} <<Total>>
\end{itemize}\vspace{1.3cm}
\textbf{Class Rank:-} <<Rank1>>\\
\textbf{Overall Rank:-} <<Rank2>>\\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Bar_Graph.png}\\
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Subject_pie_chart.png}\\
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Tot_pie_chart.png}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Here's a picture of the result:-
[image: Result]

I am trying to move both the text and the images to move more right but am unable to.

Comment: `\colorbox{yourcolor}{yourminigage}` ?

Comment: @Fran Can you please further explain? I'm new to this.

Comment: I tried to use \colorbox but it just made the color around the text black and not the entire background.

Comment: No, it should  fill completely the minipage: :` \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{blue!20}{\color{red}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
 Bla bla bla \par 
 Bla bla bla \par 
 Bla bla bla \par 
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}`  Of course, the blue will be covered by the background of  images ... except  for PNG or PDF  images with a **transparent** background.

Comment: OK, it is making the entire minipage of that colour, but it seems that my minipage's height is the same as the size of my text making it look like just a highlighted text. What I want to achieve is that my entire page have 2 different background colors. So that I get black background for my first 3 minipages and grey background for the last 2 minipages.

Comment: You need some padding?  Try with some like `\fboxsep2cm` (before of the `\colorbox`, of course).

Comment: I have added a figure which shows how my background should look like. Maybe that will help in understanding my question. As for the `\fboxsep2cm` it does not keep the background of a uniform rectangle shape as the minipages that I have created are of different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point to start. BTW, you can look for some certificate ideas [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73680/11604).

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{gray!30}
\sffamily\Huge\bfseries
\fboxsep2cm
\colorbox{black}{\color{white}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=.1\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}\hfil  
\parbox[c]{.75\linewidth}{\centering Bla bla bla\par \textcolor{red}{B}la bla bla\par Bla bla bla\par}\hfil  
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=.1\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}
\end{minipage}}
\vfill
\centering
\hfill\includegraphics[valign=c,width=.2\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill
\parbox[c]{.6\linewidth}{\centering Bla bla bla\par \textcolor{red}{B}la bla bla\par Bla bla bla\par}\hfill 

\vfill\large

\hfill\parbox{.1\linewidth}{\centering President\vspace{1.5cm}\par\dotfill}
\hfill\parbox{.1\linewidth}{\centering Dean \vspace{1.5cm}\par\dotfill}  
\hfill\parbox{.1\linewidth}{\centering Lamp Holder \vspace{1.5cm}\par\dotfill}  
\hfill\mbox{}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Also, can you tell me how to put 3 images along a vertical line at the place where you have put the 'example-image' (the one in the grey background)

Comment: @ShashankSaumya Think in the images just like a big characters... How would you type  "ABC" in a vertical column at this pace? Yes, one more minipage could be a good solution.

Comment: The mini page worked. But, for some reason it is making both my texts and images stick to the left and `\hspace` and `\hfill` did not seem to work for some reason. I have updated the question with my current code and its result. Can you please take a look and tell me what to do...

Comment: A little bit of padding did the job. Thank you so much Fran