# (Done) How to make effects in chapter sheet design and sheets decoratives

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, chapters, book-design

I am a user of www.overleaf.com and I am producing my first book. I'm a designer and I would like to make a production well done.

I researched some models of books. And I really liked this one:

[image: Chapter Sheet]

However, I don't know how to make the stitches on the chapter page. I know it is difficult, but I am asking who could give an indication, where to start. Please. Doubts:

1. I would like to know how to make this part in vector. If putting a background image would it do? Insert a vector (.eps, .svg) in the background?
2. An ornament before the chapter. I know that there is this decorative in LaTeX.
3. I am looking to capitulate in this way ... I researched and did not find it on LaTeX.

....

There is still the core of the book that I plan to use this model, which I do not know how to configure in LaTeX:

[image: Inside sheets]

1. A ribbon at the edge of the page, a golden box, with ornaments (see detail).
2. The border of the page border is an ornament.
3. Subtitle and page number separated by an ornament. I do not know how to do is this ornament = (

> > I would greatly appreciate these tips and help.

Regards!

Comment: Are you aware of the `lettrine` package? See https://ctan.org/pkg/lettrine?lang=en. And the [pgfornament](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament?lang=en) package by Alain Matthes?

Comment: You can find some examples that come pretty close under [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/194703).

Comment: Among the answer of the above link there is this [book sample](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74609/11604)  with decorations and lettrines, but the page frame remember me this [certificate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73680/11604) using niceframe. However, the easy way could be use a background image with wallpaper package instead of true ornaments.

Comment: Thank you, guys!

Comment: Friends, how set up one page for the chapter, and another for the other pages (which are not chapters).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

SOLUTIONS:

#1 - CHAPTER FIRST PAGE:

```
\chapter*{Capítulo I}
\thispagestyle{empty}
% BACKGROUND DO CAPÍTULO
%
\mbox{}
\begin{flushleft}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[width=148mm,height=206mm]{FRAME.png}}
\end{flushleft}
%

\initial*{\color{darkred}H}{ello}, welcome... bla. bla. bla....
```

Comment: You need to post a [complete solution](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), otherwise your own answer is as good as useless for other users.

Comment: Ok. thank you!!