# Draw a grid for obtaining coordinates to pass to includegraphics' viewport option

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to include only parts of an image.
For this, I use the `viewport` option of `graphicx`'s `includegraphics`.
To find the coordinates, I go by trial and error, adapting the `viewport` argument until I have it right.  This is inefficient.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}%
\includegraphics[viewport=0 0 10 10,clip]{image}
\end{document}
```

Is there some way I can easily obtain/draw a grid to efficiently select the coordinates to pass to `viewport`?
For example, when I want to draw on an image using `tikz`, I draw helplines
[according to this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/8141).
In this case, I don't want to draw at all; I just want to include a specified part of the image only.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45023/963

Comment: I think it has been discussed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57421/19356).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understood correctly, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}% option [abs] for absolute values 
\begin{document}%

\begin{overpic}[scale=0.5,unit=1mm,grid,tics=10]{tiger}
  \put(50,50){\makebox[0pt]{\colorbox{blue}{\color{white}\Huge Tiger}}}
\end{overpic}

\fbox{\includegraphics[viewport=80mm 120mm 120mm 160mm,scale=0.5,clip]{tiger}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The absolue values are scaled down, the reason why I had to double the coordinates for the eye.

Comment: Perhaps I did not phrase my question clearly.  The coordinates in this figure do not correspond to the coordinates I need to pass to `viewport` to get my desired subset of the image; for example, suppose I want to include only the right eye.  `\includegraphics[viewport=39 60 44 64,clip]{tiger}` does not give me the right eye, but a different (much smaller) area.

Comment: I set the unit to mm and scaled the image to 0.5!

Comment: I find it hard to reproduce it with my local example here.  I might be still doing something wrong.  Does it make a difference in what format the picture is?

Comment: no, the picture doesn't matter. Can you put it anywhere for a download? However, try it first with my example.

Comment: Looks like I was missing the `abs` option (I think it wasn't there in an earlier revision), but that one's pretty essential.  Got it now!

Comment: If you use a `scale=0.5` you should consider to also use `unit=0.5mm` to get the same values on the grid axes that you need to put as the viewport later on.

Answer (score 1):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% remove border option to get a tight output
\usepackage{pstricks}

\def\M{10}% columns
\def\N{10}% rows
\def\scale{1}% scale
\def\filename{shaolin}% filename


\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\scale]{\filename}}

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    gridcolor=yellow,
    subgridcolor=gray,
    subgriddiv=10,
    griddots=0,
    subgriddots=5,
    gridwidth=0.4pt,
    subgridwidth=0.2pt,
}

\psset
{
   xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\M,
   yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\N,
}


\def\Navigator{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](\M,\N)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{pspicture}}


\def\ViewPort(#1,#2)(#3,#4){\viewport(\the\dimexpr#1\psxunit,\the\dimexpr#2\psyunit)(\the\dimexpr#3\psxunit,\the\dimexpr#4\psyunit)}

\def\viewport(#1,#2)(#3,#4){\includegraphics[scale=\scale,viewport=#1 #2 #3 #4,clip]{\filename}}

\begin{document}
%\Navigator% disable it after using
\ViewPort(2,3)(6,6)
\end{document}
```

### How to use:

1. `\Nagivator` will show the grid from which we determine the viewport coordinates.

   [image]
2. `\ViewPort` is used to clip everything outside viewport.

   [image]
3. Remove `border` option in the document class to get a tight output.