# Did anybody manage to use the PhD package?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I've seen these very nice dicussion about fancy chapters:
[Fancy chapter headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23477/fancy-chapter-headings)

It seems that the packages are now called PhD

https://github.com/yannisl/phd

I can't find any documentation about it. Did somebody managed to use it (I hope so for the creator :) of the package)? If it's the case could show me a simple working example?

Comment: I suppose Yannis managed to do so :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please let us know, what you have tried and where you are running into problems. Have you read the `README.md`? Looks quite nicely documented.  Did you manage to compile `phd.dtx`? I am currently downloading that more than 100 MB but you should not expect many to do that. Therefore, you should give more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

As the comments note, I am the only user at the moment and would probably be for some time. Like many package writers the real reason for developing it, was to fulfill a need, in this case to enable me to produce beautiful books with less problems. A full `pdf` probably 3-4 months old can be found at [phd](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/phdclass/phd.pdf). It is a rather lengthy document, as the document at present is being used as a *test document*. I am actively adding material to it, but is really still not production ready.

The package, which I intend to offer it both as a class as well as a package, has two aims the first is to act as a package manager resolving conflicts and loading a number of popular as well as obscure but useful packages in order to avoid common pain points of `LaTeX2e` usage. The current version loads approximately 70-80 packages (still buggy) but is capable of typesetting the *Comprehensive List of Symbols*, including the index. I have a version (not at github) at the moment that runs happily both in `LaTeX2e` and `XeLaTeX` and to a limited extend with LuaTeX.

The second aim is to offer a new style of `LaTeX` typesetting. The user will have to only load the package or the class and type:

```
\usepackage{phd}
\cxset{template name}
```

The `templates` or `styles` follow a somewhat `CSS` type of programming, but in reality they are all keys (using pgf). With the intention to get rid of any macros in the styling or at least to minimize it.

```
\cxset{style13/.style={
 name=CHAPTER,
 chapter spaceout = none,
 numbering=arabic,
 number font-size= HUGE,
 number font-family= sffamily,
 number font-weight= bfseries,
 number color= gray!50,
 ...
 section color=teal,
 subsection align= ,
 subsection font-family= sffamily,
 subsection font-weight= bfseries,
 subsection color = teal,
 subsection font-size= large,
 subsection font-shape=,
 subparagraph number after=,
 subsubsection align=,
}}
```

The main command is intended to be `\cxset`. The intention is if you need to do any customization most of the keys have self-explanatory names and the styles are just text files.

The package at the moment, has keys for sectioning styling, document font management and hopefully soon language management. The test document at present is about 800 pages and is intended to be a free and comprehensive ebook on all things `TeX` and family. The real user manual will be about 5-10 pages, as the intention is to ease usage.

If the hyperref did not redefine almost the full breadth of LaTeX2e commands and Knuth allowed a few more maths alphabets, I would have finished six months ago. My aim is to get the package to CTAN when I am done with language management. Possibly towards the end of the year. I am also hoping to come up with a method to speed up compilation (currently takes 4-5 minutes to compile 800 pages) without compromising on the main aims of the package.

I shortened the name to conserve keystrokes! I am not too sure if this will be the final name.

Comment: I cloned your repo and produced the documentation in response to this question (LaRiFaRi beat me to the punch, though). Very extensive, and nice work! Thanks for your efforts! I will be following to see how this continues to develop and mature.

Comment: @PaulGessler Will take probably another 2-5 months to complete. I will upload a newer version by end of this month.

Answer (score 9):

Please do the following steps:

1. go to https://github.com/yannisl/phd
2. press on "Download ZIP" on the right (106 MB)
3. extract the `.zip` file somewhere you want.
4. navigate your terminal (cmd on Windows) into that folder
5. run (three lines, each followed by an Enter-stroke):

   ```
   pdflatex phd.dtx
   makeindex -s gind.ist -g phd
   pdflatex phd.dtx
   ```
6. open the `phd.pdf` which is a huge documentation

At this place, please note the authors information:

> The package as it stands is not production stable.

As a test, you can go to the very same folder and run `pdflatex MWE-02.pdf` which will result in some warnings but also in an PDF. For further questions or problems the author writes:

> If you have any difficulties with the package come and join us at
>   http://tex.stackexchange.com and post a new question or add a comment
>   at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45023/963. or send me a message at
>   yannislaz at gmail.com

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've downloaded the package did the three comand lines and opened the documentation. I tried to compile the most basic example.


\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chaptersx}
\cxset{style13}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}

It returns ! LaTeX Error: File `chaptersx.sty' not found.



I have a chapterx.sty in the PhD folder but not one with an s

Comment: @Fabien Yes, I had similar problems. I fear that you have to wait some more time. until this gets stable. I never used this package (just once in order to help you) so I am not a good person for support. You should stick to Yiannis and/or wait 2-5 month. Sorry for that unpleasant response and good luck to you.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'm excited to see the final version of the package.