# Reduce font size to fit container

Tags: fontsize, fit

I would like to create a series of containers in the same size but with different contents, making such that the contained text reduces its font size if it would not fit the container otherwise.

Is there any way to automatically reduce font size to avoid overflowing of the container?

This question is a duplicate of [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize).

Comment: You can use `\resizebox` and set the desired fixed height or width. Please provide a MWE (minimal working example) to clearly and better understand your question.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33417/adjust-font-size-on-the-fly

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26002/5764); [Adjust font size on-the-fly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33417/5764)

Comment: @Werner, thank you for the links. I believe that "[Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize)" is talking about my same problem. I'll mark this as a duplicate.