# Center, Scale, and Wrap Text atop an Image

Tags: fontspec, overpic

Which LaTeX packages can I use to center, scale, and wrap text such that the following conditions are met:

- If the text isn't a wide as the container, scale the up text to fit.
- If the text is wider than the container, scale the text down to fit.
- In the case that text is scaled down, wrap the text to prevent ending up with one tiny, unreadable paragraph.

I've tried `parbox`, `pbox`, `tabular`, and `adjustbox`, none quite meeting all three conditions.

Here's the gist:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\headingText[Color=FFFFFF]{KnowYourProduct}

\newcommand{\myFrame}[1]  {
    \begin{overpic}[width=6cm,height=3cm,grid,tics=10]{Template}
        \put (8,25) {
            {\contourlength{0.025em}\contour{black}{\headingText #1}}
        }
    \end{overpic}
}   

\begin{document}

\myFrame{Title}
\myFrame{This Is A Long Title}
\myFrame{This title is so long that if you're still reading it you may want to reevaluate how you are presently squandering your personal time.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Done. Was there was an implied "Learn a little more and try this again" with the previous comment? Should I be modifying this question?

Comment: No sorry, I was choosing the wrong stock comment ;-) It was fine! Welcome to TeX.SX (this was no stock comment! ;-))

Comment: The question is when does text become too small to be readable.

Comment: egreg has a related answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33417/adjust-font-size-on-the-fly/33897#33897.  I had a related answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/making-the-text-fit-in-a-specific-space-in-latex/123650#123650.  And then there is this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I had enough problems without having to deal with your fonts, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\tempwidth}
\newlength{\temptest}
\newcount{\templines}

\newcommand{\myFrame}[1]% #1 = text
{\settowidth{\tempwidth}{#1}%
\ifdim\tempwidth>6cm \templines=0
  \loop\advance\templines by 1
    \temptest = 2\baselineskip% 6cm (width) / 3cm (height) = 2
    \multiply\temptest by \templines
    \multiply\temptest by \templines
    \ifdim\tempwidth>\temptest\repeat
  \divide\temptest by \templines
  \fbox{\resizebox*{6cm}{3cm}{\parbox{\temptest}{#1}}}%
\else \fbox{\resizebox*{6cm}{3cm}{#1}}%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\myFrame{Title}

\myFrame{This Is A Long Title}

\myFrame{This title is so long that if you're still reading it you may want to reevaluate how you are presently squandering your personal time.}

\end{document}
```

[image: boxes]

Comment: Not looking for the behavior in the middle box, but I'm working with this on a better solution _including_ all my fonts, etc. I think height is also a constraint in the first case: essentially, there's a magical goldilocks zone here.

Comment: The \parbox solution can be used for smaller titles, but at some point it breaks down.

Comment: Good point. I really had no idea how deep this combination of wants was going to go.