# Forcing a Document into a Single page

Tags: page-breaking

I've been using `TeX` for a while, so when I suggested my company compile its daily newsletter using LaTex, rather than an hour and a half of someone's time, I got tasked with actual implementation.  I'm near done, but because the data is generated dynamically - I'm not sure exactly how much text is going to be generated an placed into each article.  I've use `\vspace{\fill}` to strategically deal with an undersized newsletter - but I can't figure out what to do in the case of an oversized one.

Is there a way to force `TeX` to compile into a single page, every time?  I mean, I'd rather (honest to god) just have the text cut off the way it does horizontally.

I found this [this incredibly similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/unbreakable-block), and tried everything listed there.  I've looked into `samepage`, but that environment just breaks the page anyway after a while.  Additionally, `\parbox` was suggested - but when I wrapped the whole document in that, an overfull box it just caused it to break the page before.  `needspace` will do the same thing.

I've been developing this process over the last few days, periodically breaking to spend hours searching the Google Box or StackExchange for answers, to no avail.  Anyone?

Comment: You could iterate through a number of steps to make the oversized content fit on a page by following some of the solutions presented in [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26002/5764).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're happy just truncating the bottom of the content, then you can force into a minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{\linewidth}
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

But notice how I set the height of the `minipage` to zero.  This makes it stay on page one.

Is your company *really* going to be impressed with LaTeX if you truncate things?

Provided that you know your newsletter is never going to be longer than 2-3 pages.  There is probably a way you work around this.  I'm thinking that you don't set the height of the minipage, save its height to a minipage, the run latex again reading in the value of the minipage's height and set the height of the document's page to the same value.  I'm not sure I know how to do such an elaborate work-around, but I'm sure if you post a question

> **How do I define the dimensions of a page to accommodate its contents:  even if unusually large?**

someone will come up with an interesting solution.
Of course, such a solution only makes sense if the newsletter is something only posted electronically and not printed.

> **OR**

If you know the contents are only be slightly larger than the page, you can use `graphicx` package and rescale the box so it does in fact fit on the page.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
%% for demo purposes only
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent\scalebox{.94}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.06\linewidth}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

This is a document for which `\enlargethispage` wouldn't suffice.  But by selecting appropriate values for the scale factor and the `\linewidth` (I chose near reciprocals), you can get something fairly decent looking.

Comment: The unfortunate truth is that I can't make guarantees about pretty much anything, and this is meant to be distributed electronically as well as being printed and posted, alternate page sizes aren't really an option.  I chose to truncate it based on some additional problems, and I have some alternate compile scripts that pull longer or shorter previews of the articles for fine tuning.  This is a V1, and I'm sure I'll be making more changes as I have time in the future - but that's the design choice.  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: The minipage solution seems to shift all content slightly to the right...

Comment: @Jasha Probably could use a `\noindent` to prevent paragraph indentation from happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [savetrees](https://ctan.org/pkg/savetrees) package to shrink your document.

There are 3 modes: `subtle`, `moderate` and `extreme`. It is recommended to try `subtle` mode first before trying other modes.

```
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}

% rest of your LaTex document...
```

See the [documentation](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/savetrees/savetrees.pdf) for further details.

Interestingly, it is [used](https://www.silverf0x00.com/shrinking-a-latex-paper-to-fit-under-the-page-limits/#savetrees) by PHD students to make their papers fit under the page limit. That article contains many more wonderful tricks about document shrinking.