# How to put whole of a text on a single page?

Tags: fontsize

I want to put whole of a text on a single page. I don't have constraint on the text font. So if the text was too long, the text font should be small. How can I do this automatically using LaTeX? For example, if I write the `\lipsum`, the printed document should contain exactly one page.

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize). You could create a box the size of the page to fit the text in.

Answer (score 2):

With `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting}
\tcbset{width=(\linewidth-2mm),colback=green!10!white,boxsep=1mm}
\begin{document}
  \tcboxfit[height=(\textheight-2mm)]{\lipsum\lipsum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without colors:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{width=(\linewidth),colback=white,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxrule=0mm}
\begin{document}
  \tcboxfit[height=(\textheight),enhanced jigsaw]{\lipsum\lipsum}
\end{document}
```

Environment form:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcboxfit{\mybox}[1][]{%
colback=red!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,
width=(\linewidth),
height=(\textheight),
left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxrule=0mm,
enhanced jigsaw,
#1}

\begin{document}
  \mybox[colback=yellow]%
    {\lipsum}
  \mybox[colback=white]%
    {\lipsum}
  \mybox%
    {\lipsum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have added three pages. You can put everything inside a single `\mybox{...}` and content will be contained in a single page.