# rotate \rput \parbox write on image

Tags: graphics, pstricks, rotating

I want to create the illusion of a note stuck on top of the page.  Here I have typed and saved in photoshop 
[image: rotated post-it note]
and then added to the xeLatex document with `\includegraphics[angle =30 ]{paper.png}`  paper.png is at http://www.bluehillsfarm.com/images/paper.png
I would like to be able to type comments on the post-it note into TeX and have them auto-size, i.e. if the professor's comment was longer it would shrink to a smaller font to fit the same-sized post-it note.
Here is my MWE but the comment is not positioned right on the note.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks}

\newpsstyle{gridstyle}
{
   gridwidth=0.1pt,
subgridwidth=0.05pt, 
gridlabels=5pt,
gridcolor=green, 
subgridcolor=white, 
subgriddiv=2
}

\psset{style=gridstyle}

\newsavebox\IBox

% Ratio of the imported graphics width to the line width.
\def\RatioToLineWidth{0.95}
\savebox\IBox
{%
\includegraphics[width=\RatioToLineWidth\linewidth]{paper.png}%
}


\newdimen\width
\newdimen\height
\width=\wd\IBox
\height=\ht\IBox


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset
{
xunit=0.1\width,
yunit=0.1\height
}

\begin{pspicture}(\width,\height)       
\rput[lb](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
{\parbox{4cm}{I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. I want this text to be justified. }}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:
[image: text is on bottom-right]

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to a [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) approach, here's one possibility:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newdimen\fontdim
\newdimen\upperfontdim
\newdimen\lowerfontdim
\newif\ifmoreiterations
\fontdim12pt

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{fitbox}[2]{% \begin{fitbox}{<width>}{<height>} stuff \end{fitbox}
  \def\buildbox{%
    \setbox0\vbox{\hbox{\minipage{#1}%
      \fontsize{\fontdim}{1.2\fontdim}%
      \selectfont%
      \stuff%
    \endminipage}}%
    \dimen@\ht0
    \advance\dimen@\dp0
  }
  \def\stuff{\BODY}% Store environment body
  \buildbox
  % Compute upper and lower bounds
  \ifdim\dimen@>#2
    \loop
      \fontdim.5\fontdim % Reduce font size by half
      \buildbox%
    \ifdim\dimen@>#2 \repeat
    \lowerfontdim\fontdim
    \upperfontdim2\fontdim
    \fontdim1.5\fontdim
  \else
    \loop
      \fontdim2\fontdim % Double font size
      \buildbox%
    \ifdim\dimen@<#2 \repeat
    \upperfontdim\fontdim
    \lowerfontdim.5\fontdim
    \fontdim.75\fontdim
  \fi
  % Now try to find the optimum size
  \loop
    %\message{Bounds: \the\lowerfontdim\space
    %         \the\fontdim\space \the\upperfontdim^^J}
    \buildbox%
    \ifdim\dimen@>#2
      \moreiterationstrue
      \upperfontdim\fontdim
      \advance\fontdim\lowerfontdim
      \fontdim.5\fontdim
    \else
      \advance\dimen@-#2
      \ifdim\dimen@<10pt
        \lowerfontdim\fontdim
        \advance\fontdim\upperfontdim
        \fontdim.5\fontdim
        \dimen@\upperfontdim
        \advance\dimen@-\lowerfontdim
        \ifdim\dimen@<.2pt
          \moreiterationsfalse
        \else
          \moreiterationstrue
        \fi
      \else
        \moreiterationsfalse
      \fi
    \fi
  \ifmoreiterations \repeat
  \box0% Typeset content
}
\makeatother

\newsavebox\ImageBox
\savebox\ImageBox{\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{paper}}

\newcommand\MyNote[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west] (image)
  {\usebox\ImageBox};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at ([shift={(0.065,-20pt)}]image.north west)
  {\begin{fitbox}{0.6\wd\ImageBox}{.6\ht\ImageBox}
    #2
\end{fitbox}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\MyNote{Some short text}

\noindent\MyNote[rotate=30,transform shape]{Some test text and here we add some more text to see what is happening with the font size }

\noindent\MyNote{Some test text and here we add some more text to see what is happening with the font size and here we add some more text to see what is happening with the font size and here we add some more text to see what is happening with the font size and here we add some more text to see what is happening with the font size and here we add some more text to see what is happening with the font size}

\end{document}
```

To have the font adjust to the size, I used [`Werner's answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26006/3954) to [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26002/3954)

Answer (score 1):

Here I use nested `\stackinset`s, using the paper image provided by the OP and the received stamp at http://www.xpressmarking.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Received-Trodat-S-Printy.png

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{30}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.1cm}{\parbox{3in}{\bfseries\scriptsize\sffamily\lipsum[4]}}{%
  \stackinset{r}{2cm}{t}{1.5cm}{\includegraphics[width=1in]{Received-Trodat-S-Printy}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=4in]{paper}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox\IBox
\sbox\IBox{\includegraphics{paper}}
\makeatletter
\def\setPaper{\@ifnextchar[\setPaper@i{\setPaper@i[0]}}
\def\setPaper@i[#1](#2,#3)#4{\rput{#1}(#2,#3){%
  \usebox\IBox\psTextFrame[linestyle=none](-\wd\IBox,0)(0,\ht\IBox){%
    \parbox{0.7\wd\IBox}{#4}}}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setPaper(3,-3){\lipsum[1]}

\setPaper[45](0.5\linewidth,-12cm){\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]