# How to shrink in 16:9 beamer mode?

Tags: beamer

I am using the 16:9 mode when preparing `beamer` slides
In the MWE below, in the second frame, the text is only compressed vertically,
leaving a lot of empty space on the right side; which could be used to extend the text length. Is there any way to extend the \textwidth, AND reduce \textheight (in frame of shrink, or something similar)? It would improve considerably the appearance.
(sorry for closing, I was away for a while)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Number 1}{Frame 1}
\blindtext[2]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[shrink]{Frame Number 2}{Frame 2}
\blindtext[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're doing and doesn't work?

Comment: Can you please make a MWE that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize. However it is probably easier if you would just select the fontsize so that the text fits.

Comment: @samcarter I think you are right (there is a selection there :). Can I replace shrink with something different?

Comment: @katang You could use `{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \blindtext[2]}` and adapt the numbers accordingly.

Comment: @samcarter Unfortunately, I have also figures, tables, etc.

Comment: @katang For such elements `\resizebox` comes to minds. But I am nut sure if this can be done in an automatic way.

Answer (score 1):

`[shrink]` geometrically scales down the output, while keeping the aspect ration of width and height, everything else would result in a distortion of the output. For square paper sizes, this works perfectly well, all other paper sizes will exhibit your problem.

In order to fill the whole slide, you don't want to use any form of `shrink`, manually use a smaller font size. Tables will also use this smaller size, but if the images also should be smaller, their size has to be adjusted additionally.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Number 1}{Frame 1}
\blindtext[2]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame Number 2}{Frame 2}
\smaller
\blindtext[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]