# Can algorithm of shrink in beamer frame be improved?

Tags: beamer

I used to [shrink] routinely beamer slides, 
when just a few percent more content is on the page, that could fit by default. It makes no noticeable aesthetic change in the size of the font, but does not degrade the beauty with clipped object or text. Why I asked 
[How to shrink in 16:9 beamer mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329037/how-to-shrink-in-169-beamer-mode) is, that the changed aspect ratio has an impact on the aesthetic of the frame. 
It looks like the algorithm of shrink simply adjusts the height of the content to the height of the frame. As shown by the MWE below, the shrinking, what can be hardly noticed in 4:3 mode, is quite ugly in 16:9 mode.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Number 1}
\blindtext[1]\par\includegraphics[width=4.8cm]{example-image-golden}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[shrink]{Frame Number 1}
\blindtext[1]\par\includegraphics[width=4.8cm]{example-image-golden}\qquad
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `shrink=5` which looks a bit better

[image]

the manual says:

> The best way to use this option is to identify frames that are overly
>   full, but in which all text absolutely has to be fit on a single
>   frame. Then start specifying first shrink=5, then shrink=10, and so
>   on, until no warning is issued any more (or just ignore the warning
>   when things look satisfactory).
>
> Using this option is very evil. It will result in changes of the font
>   size from slide to slide, which is a typographic nightmare. Its usage
>   can always be avoided by restructuring and simplifying frames, which
>   will result in a better presentation.

Comment: A really evil answer.

Comment: @David Carlisle I agree with your arguments. I am searching a "less evil" algorithm, for very slightly oversized slides. Say, increasing the with, which once decreases the empty space on the side and second reduces the overshot of the height. Then re-build the frame with the changed size. As I demonstrated, the "evilness" depends on the aspect ratio. The present algoritm works perfectly with aspect ratio 1, tolerable with 4:3, and "evil" with 16:9.

Comment: @katang they are not "my" arguments (I didn't even know of the option) the text was just the first bit of text about shrink in the manual. But it isn't really an _algorithm_ at all, it doesn't reset the text, it simply scales it to fit.