# Make Table of Contents fit in one page

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, page-breaking

My Table of Contents does not fit on one page, two chapters go to a new page and the rest of the page is empty, is it somehow possible to fix this?

Comment: You may try using a dedicated package like `titletoc` or `tocloft` to play with the vertical spacings and/or font size.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize/262211#262211) old answer of mine (which defines the `\fitbox` macro -- its name should be self-explanatory) you could do:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \begingroup
    \@fileswfalse
    \fitbox\textheight{\oldtableofcontents}
  \endgroup
  \if@filesw
     \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@toc\endcsname
     \immediate\openout \csname tf@toc\endcsname \jobname.toc\relax
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

### Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fp,graphicx}
  \setlength\unitlength{1cm}

\makeatletter

\def\accur@cy{0.999}

\newcommand{\fitbox}[3][\textwidth]{%
  \@tempdima#2
  \edef\@wd{\strip@pt\dimexpr#1\relax}
  \def\r@tio{1}
  \@temptokena={\scalebox{\r@tio}{\parbox{\@wd pt}{{#3}}}}
  \setbox0=\vbox{\the\@temptokena}
  \@tempdimb=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
  \FPdiv\r@tio{\strip@pt\@tempdima}{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}
  \FProot\r@tio{\r@tio}{2}
  \FPdiv\@wd{\@wd}{\r@tio}
  \fitbox@adjust
  \setbox0=\vbox{\the\@temptokena}
  \box0
}
\newcommand{\fitbox@adjust}{%
  \@tempcnta\z@
  \def\rel@rror@rec{0}
  \fitbox@adjust@
}
\newcommand{\fitbox@adjust@}{%
  \advance\@tempcnta by 1
  \ifnum\@tempcnta<10
   \FPiflt\rel@rror@rec\accur@cy
    \setbox0=\vbox{\the\@temptokena}
    \@tempdimb=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax
    \FPdiv\rel@rror@rec{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}{\strip@pt\@tempdima}
    \FPdiv\r@tio{\r@tio}{\rel@rror@rec}
    \FPmul\@wd{\@wd}{\rel@rror@rec}
    \fitbox@adjust@
   \fi
  \fi
}

\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \begingroup
    \@fileswfalse
    \fitbox\textheight{\oldtableofcontents}
  \endgroup
  \if@filesw
     \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@toc\endcsname
     \immediate\openout \csname tf@toc\endcsname \jobname.toc\relax
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\section{hello world}

\end{document}
```

### Output

#### Before

[image: output_1]

#### After

[image: output_2]

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the space set *before* each chapter title in the ToC. The default is `1em`. Either use [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.8em}
```

or via an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{1.0em}{0.8em}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.8em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\chapter{Third chapter}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}
\chapter{Fifth chapter}
\chapter{Sixth chapter}
\chapter{Seventh chapter}
\chapter{Eighth chapter}
\chapter{Ninth chapter}
\chapter{Tenth chapter}
\chapter{Eleventh chapter}
\chapter{Twelfth chapter}
\chapter{Thirteenth chapter}
\chapter{Fourteenth chapter}

\end{document}
```

Before the update:

[image]

After the update:

[image]

You can tweak the adjusted spacing to make things fit your setup. For example, if you have sections in the ToC as well, you may not want to adjust the value of `\cftbeforechapskip` quite as much, and perhaps also adjust `\cftbeforesecskip`.

---

The above should work for both `book` and `report` document classes. If you're using [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir), you can do something similar to what `tocloft` provides. In the preamble, adjust `\cftbeforechapterskip`:

```
\documentclass[...]{memoir}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0.8em}% Change to suit your needs...

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this MWE reproducing the problem:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum} % for dummy text loop 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,21} {\chapter{blabla\x} \lipsum[\x]}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

For consistency with the rest of the book, I would avoid changes in the layout (margins and/or space around title, `\enlargethispage{}`, etc.) or resizing a box containing the ToC, as this might produce a non standard font size (that will be not used in the rest of the book).

My suggestion is simpler: use a smaller standard font (e.g.,  `\footnotesize`), reduce a little the interline spacing (e.g.,    `\linespread{.85}`) or mix both approaches for a more subtle  style change:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum} % for dummy text loop 
\begin{document}
{\linespread{.95}\small\tableofcontents}
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,21} {\chapter{blabla\x} \lipsum[\x]}
\end{document}
```

[image: solution]