# Prevent page break before bibliography (LNCS template)

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, page-breaking, lncs

I write a paper with the LaTeX LNCS template. The paper should have specified number of pages. So, I need to put the bibliography section on the same page as the table of contents. I searched and trid different ways, but I can not figure out how to make this happen.

The biblography part looks like

```
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{5}
 %
 \bibitem{t1}
 \end{thebibliography}
 \end{document}
```

Here are the packages I use:

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
```

Comment: Please show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of how your document looks like. You may also want to show us where you got the template from.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a minimal example of the code you have?

Comment: I added the bibliography part.

Comment: I use sharelatex site and using this site LNCS template

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not really a full MWE, have a look at the link in my first comment to see how to create a helpful MWE for us. I have retagged your question, since the code you showed us suggests you are not using the package `biblatex`.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in latex.

Comment: as you said there is no biblatex package. what should I do?

Comment: The template defines the layout, that is the easy start the sites are talking about.  Still  have to have some basic knowledge of the language LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template that ShareLaTeX offers the bibliography section is done by hand in the end. I think this isn't really necessary here. Unless you are not bound to it you could use the canonical `\bibliographystyle`-`\bibliography` pair and define a custom toc macro which temporarilly disables `clearpage`:

```
\newcommand\TOCwithBibliography[2][plain]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \tableofcontents
    \vspace{2em}
    \bibliographystyle{#1}
    \bibliography{#2}
  \endgroup
  \clearpage
}
```

Then use `\TOCwithBibliography[<bib style>]{<bib file>}` at the point your contents+bibliography page should be printed. Of course you could also hard-code the bib style and the bib file information like

```
...
    \vspace{2em}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}% or whatever style
    \bibliography{testbib}% name of your .bib file
  \endgroup
...
```

But I don't think this is necessarily better.

## Complete Example

<sub>*using [`llncs.cls`](http://www.fpl.uni-kl.de/conferences/patmos/patmos00/p_neu/llncs.cls) v2.6*</sub>

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
  @article{test123,
    author  = {Rufus Dufus},
    title   = {Some article},
    journal = {Some journal},
    year    = {2017}
 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} 

\newcommand\TOCwithBibliography[2][plain]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \tableofcontents
    \vspace{2em}
    \bibliographystyle{#1}
    \bibliography{#2}
  \endgroup
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\TOCwithBibliography{testbib}
\nocite{*}
\pagestyle{headings}
\chapter{foo}
\chapter{bar}
\chapter{baz}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: example_rendered]

## Addendum

Note that in the complete example I commented out the `tocbibind` package as it is quite strange to force the bibliography into the TOC when it is on the same page.

Moreover the alternative approach I showed above may come in handy if you want to redefine `\tableofcontents` (if you want to keep the markup untouched):

```
\let\oldtoc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \oldtoc
    \vspace{2em}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{yourbibfile}
  \endgroup
  \clearpage
}
```

Lastly you might want to be aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349361/make-table-of-contents-fit-in-one-page/349369#349369) which deals with forcing the TOC onto one page.

Comment: @JachobTailor -- wow, I would have been fine if I just saved your document. :)