# Beamer bibliography over EXACTLY two pages, no matter how many references?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies

I have a requirement to output the bibliography for a beamer over **exactly two pages**, no matter how many references (output will be infinitely zoomable .pdf).

```
\documentclass[8pt, xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You would need something like these answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize to find the required font size.