# set a fix height and width for a style in latex tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a rectangular style in latex and I want to fix the size of that. however, in the setting I can only set the minimum width and minimum height. Here is my style;

```
direct/.style={rectangle, minimum height =4 cm, rounded corners=4.4mm, minimum width=10 cm, fill=red!15, draw,thick,},
```

And then the size of this shape change based on the text in it. I want a constant rectangular. Do you know how I can solve this? Thanks

Comment: You are trying to draw a rectangle as a style of a node. node have a content to respect `{}` and thus must keep a size that contains that content. If you want a rectangle of exact height and width, you need to draw it as a path aka: `\draw (A) rectangle (B)` where A and B are nodes or coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

[Anis' comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674720/set-a-fix-height-and-width-for-a-style-in-latex-tikz#comment1676221_674720) already tells you a lot. Just as add-on, I want to mention few possibilities if you really have content in your nodes and would like to have a homogeneous size. Without knowing your context and needs, mine is just speculation. Hopefully it serves as starting point.

- You could use `text width` set to the `minimum width` (or slightly less) and let TikZ wrap your text (to change alignment, use the `align` key). This approach prevents the node content, if too long, to exceed the minimum desired width, but it does not prevent the same for the height, though.
- You could then define a style to scale by hand the font, using e.g. the `relsize` package. You would use this style to manually reduce the node content when needed. This requires some fine tuning, though.
- You could automatise the previous approach, by getting inspired [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26002/128737). I took one of the answers there in my example below. The idea is to automatically scale the node content to fit a box that in turn fits your node desired size.

As general advice, you might have a look in general to the PGF manual, maybe starting with the minimal introduction to TikZ to get a general overview. Both documents are [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Here a proof of concept.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,environ,relsize}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\fixedWidth}{10cm}
\newcommand{\fixedHeigth}{4cm}

\tikzset{
    direct/.style={
        rectangle,
        minimum height=\fixedHeigth,
        minimum width=\fixedWidth,
        rounded corners=4.4mm,
        fill=red!15,
        draw,
        thick
    },
    fontsmaller/.style={font=\smaller[#1]}
}

% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26004/128737
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{fitbox}[2]{%
    \minipage{#1}%
    \sbox0{\minipage{#1}\strut\BODY\strut\endminipage}%
    \Gscale@div\factor{#2}{\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}%
    \relscale{\factor}%
    \BODY
    \endminipage
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [direct] (N1) {Short};
        \node [direct, below = of N1] (N2) {
            Very long text whose width exceeds the specified minimum
            width of the node and hence the desired shape
        };
        \node [direct, below = of N2, text width=10cm] (N3) {\lipsum[1-2]};
        \node [direct, below = of N3, text width=10cm, fontsmaller=3.5] (N4) {\lipsum[1-2]};
        \node [direct, below = of N4, text width=10cm] {
            \begin{fitbox}{\fixedWidth}{\fixedHeigth}
                \lipsum[1-2]
            \end{fitbox}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to typeset the text in a fixed shape, and telling nothing about it to Ti*k*Z. If the text will not fit, it will leak...

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\FixedSizeText}[3]{% width, height
    \begin{minipage}[c][#2][c]{#1}%
        #3%
    \end{minipage}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tikzset{my rect/.style={
        rectangle, draw=red, inner sep=0pt, rounded corners},
    }
    \path (0,0) node [my rect]{\FixedSizeText{3cm}{2cm}{A little text}}
        (3,0) node [my rect]{\FixedSizeText{3cm}{2cm}{A little text}}
        (0,-3) node [my rect]{\FixedSizeText{3cm}{2cm}{Longer text that will arguably not fill in the minipage, and so the thing will be leaked around}}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps You search for something like this (equals boxes, not the same quantity of text inside):
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,fit to height=8cm, width=10cm,
        colback=gray!35!black!20!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title=Fit box (8cm),
        drop fuzzy shadow]
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \quad
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,fit to height=8cm, width=10cm,
        colback=gray!35!black!20!white,colframe=gray!75!black,title=Fit box (8cm),
        drop fuzzy shadow]
        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```