# Automatically resizes text to fit perfectly within its bounds

Tags: scaling, resize

I am looking for the same functionality as simc/auto_size_text,
a flutter widget that automatically resizes text to fit perfectly within its bounds.

However, I want to achieve this for physically printed flashcards at various sizes. Particularly A6 paper, but a template that I can alter for different page sizes, A4 to business card, would be best.

```
\fillpage{}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
?
?
```

Can LaTex do this? What command to search for, or should I start making a python script to go directly to pdf?

Comment: Have a look at the fitting library from tcolorbox

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz shouldn't that be an answer? AFAICT that's pretty much exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @WillieWong maybe, but the question lacks a MWE and I don't fancy creating one... If you'd like to write an answer, please go ahead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26002/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fitting` library from [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) can be used to fit text to boxes. Below is a bare minimum example; see the `tcolorbox` documentation for how to adjust other properties of the box. Paper size can be set via `geometry` package.

*Note:* the library never increases the text size by itself. Instead, you need to specify a base font size that is known to be too big, after which the library will scale it down to fit. (You can compare the effects by removing the `\tcbset{fit basedim=35pt}` line from the code below.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm}  % Allow arbitrary font scaling for Computer Modern
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}  % Just so that the examples fit on the same page
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for dummy text

\begin{document}

\tcbset{fit basedim=35pt}  % tcb doesn't enlarge text; it starts with this base dimensional and shrinks text to fit
    % So if you need the font to possibly scale __up__ you need to specify a larger size to boot. 

\tcboxfit[height=5.8in,width=4.1in]{\lipsum[1]}  % A6 size, portrait

\tcboxfit[width=5.8in,height=4.1in]{\lipsum[2]}  % A6 size, landscape

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Note: the library never increases the text size by itself. Instead, you need to specify a base font size that is known to be too big, after which" Critical info, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use [`shapepar`](https://ctan.org/pkg/shapepar) together with `\resizebox`.

**Caveats**:

- `\resizebox` has its first two arguments "width" and "height"; but `\shapepar`'s `\rectangleshape` has them as "height" first and then "width". Be careful when you prepare your document.
- `\shapepar` can only, as its name suggests, shape a paragraph. So no *displayed* math (inline math is okay) or anything that adjusts the vertical spacing.
- `\Shapepar` works on entire paragraphs; you need to make sure that the paragraph is terminated (via either a blank line or a `\par`) if you wrap it in `\resizebox`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{shapepar}   % Use shapepar to build the correct shape of text block
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Use resizebox to scale it to the right size
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% Note that \Shapepar requires the paragraph to be terminated. 
% This means we must include either a blank line or a \par.
\resizebox{5.8in}{!}{\Shapepar{\rectangleshape{4.1}{5.8}} \lipsum[1]\par}

\resizebox{4.1in}{!}{\Shapepar{\rectangleshape{5.8}{4.1}} \lipsum[2]\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]