# Including sample output as whole pages

Tags: pdfpages, sourcecode, examples

What would be the best way to include sample LaTeX output, in the form of (reduced) whole pages, into another document that discusses its typesetting?

I am thinking of creating one (**"example"**) document with all the examples, and tagging each one with `\label`; in the **main** document, I would fetch the labels with the help of the [xr](http://ctan.org/pkg/xr) package and include the appropriate page range with [pdfpages](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). A first problem: I can expect to know the number of pages to include for each example, but how can I tell `pdfpages` to include from `\pageref{exampleA}` to `\pageref{exampleA}+1`? (Presumably there's some package that can calculate `\pageref{exampleA}+1` in a form that I can pass to `pdfpages`. But which one?)

So far so good. This has the advantage that it's easy for the example document to use a different style than the documentation; but I need to manually ensure that the examples are generated with the same code that I describe in the main document. This is **not essential,** but could be handy. Perhaps I could also include latex code from the example document into the main document by somehow retrieving and line ranges (how?) and passing them to `\lstinputlisting` of the [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package), but I'd expect that to be more trouble than it's worth.

Can anyone recommend a better workflow? Are there better-suited packages that I am unaware of?

To summarize: I'm interested in the best way to show whole pages as sample output in a document that discusses its typesetting. Including PDF pages from another document, and including source lines from another TeX file, are possible approaches but not **necessarily** the best ones: I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: In part 2 of my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166418/put-entire-thesis-on-one-a0-poster/166442#166442, I show how to include a series of whole pages from one document as a series of slightly reduced (and clipped) figures in another document.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen this question+answers before but certainly didn't connect it to my problem. Did you _have_ to use `\includegraphics` (and a ton of pdf files) instead of `pdfpages`? The latter is clearly designed for managing all of the generated pages, whether one-up or n-up, so maybe I won't be able to use it for this? (I could try to get it to work, I know, but I don't want to waste a lot of time barking up the wrong tree.)

Comment: I did work with many PDF files, though in my case it was easy because Acrobat (installed on my system) will break a document into many files xxx_1, xxx_2, etc., at the click of a button.  One commenter to my answer, Raphael, noted that "On GNU/Linux, splitting a document into single pages is easily achieved by pdftk in.pdf burst output out_%04d.pdf (pick suitably many digits for enumeration)."  If you have a preferable way, by all means use it.  I was just trying to get you started in one form or another.

Comment: I'm certainly not set on one approach. I'd prefer to avoid breaking up my file into single pages, but I'm flexible; and indeed I _am_ asking for alternatives!

Comment: I've discovered that `\includegraphics[page=2]{filename}` is a valid syntax, which will alleviate the need for you to split the target file into subfiles.

Comment: What about `pgfpages`? This way you can keep everything in one file (I think).

Comment: @cfr thanks for the tip, I'll check it out. (`\includegraphics` can also keep everything in one file, it turned out, but `pgfpages` might have other advantages.)

Comment: @alexis Well `\includegraphics` needs *two* as far as I know - one for the stuff-to-be-included and one for the stuff-to-do-the-including. `pgfpages` really does need only one. Whether this is advantageous or not probably depends on the details of your workfolow ;).

Comment: I see, yes, that would be great if I can get it to work out (for independent reasons --- I may need to use a different document class for the displayed document). I'll check the `pgfpages` documentation with this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first I need a multipage document that I want to insert.  So, that others can compile it, I grabbed my MWE from [Is there such a thing as a `\mathrule`? (rounded endcaps)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps/161309#161309), which creates a 2-page output (name this source as useroundrule.tex):

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0 %%% to see how it works in the pdf code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}% Used for testing; not needed for \math(v)rule's
\parindent=0pt
\makeatletter

\newcommand\mathrule[3][0pt]{%
  \ifdim#2>#3\math@hrule[#1]{#2}{#3}\else\math@vrule[#1]{#2}{#3}\fi}

\newcommand\math@hrule[3][0pt]{%
  \gdef\mystery@factor{0.07}%
 \@tempdima=#3%
  \rule[#1]{0pt}{#3}% Needed to account for .5\@tempdima vertical offset of rounded rule
  \raisebox{.5\@tempdima+#1}{%
    \makebox[#2][l]{\kern-.5\@tempdima\@@mathrule{#2}{#3}}}%
}

\newcommand\math@vrule[3][0pt]{%
  \gdef\mystery@factor{0.0}%
 \@tempdima=#2%
  \rule[#1]{0pt}{#3}% Needed to account for .5\@tempdima vertical offset of rounded rule
  \raisebox{-.0\@tempdima+#1}{%
    \kern0.5\@tempdima%
    \rotatebox{90}{\kern-0.5\@tempdima\makebox[#3][l]{\@@mathrule{#3}{#2}}}%
    \kern0.5\@tempdima}%
}

\def\@@mathrule#1#2{%
  \@tempdimb=#2%
  \@tempdima=\dimexpr#1-\mystery@factor\@tempdimb%Why 0.07 for \math@hrule?
  \pdfliteral{%
    q []0 d %
    1 J %  set line cap to rounded ends
    \strip@pt\@tempdimb\space w \strip@pt\@tempdimb\space 0 m %
    \strip@pt\@tempdima\space 0 l S Q }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mathrule{60bp}{1bp}\par
\rule{60bp}{1bp}\par
x\mathrule[-1pt]{20bp}{1bp}x\mathrule{20bp}{1bp}x\par
x\rule[-1pt]{20bp}{1bp}x\rule{20bp}{1bp}x\par
\stackunder[2pt]{\rule{60bp}{3bp}}{\mathrule{60bp}{3bp}}\par
\fbox{\mathrule[-1ex]{4ex}{.5ex}}\fbox{\rule[-1ex]{4ex}{.5ex}}\par
\fbox{\mathrule[+1ex]{4ex}{.5ex}}\fbox{\rule[+1ex]{4ex}{.5ex}}\par
\clearpage
\mathrule{1bp}{60bp} \rule{1bp}{60bp}\par
x\mathrule[-1pt]{1bp}{20bp}x\mathrule{1bp}{20bp}x%
  \rule[-1pt]{1bp}{20bp}x\rule{1bp}{20bp}x\par
x\rule[-1pt]{1bp}{20bp}x\rule{1bp}{20bp}x\par
\stackunder[2pt]{\rule{3bp}{10bp}\mathrule{3bp}{10bp}}%
  {\mathrule{3bp}{10bp}\rule{3bp}{10bp}}\par
\fbox{\mathrule[-1ex]{.5ex}{4ex}}\fbox{\rule[-1ex]{.5ex}{4ex}}\par
\fbox{\mathrule[+1ex]{.5ex}{4ex}}\fbox{\rule[+1ex]{.5ex}{4ex}}\par
\end{document}
```

So compile that to make a two page document (useroundrule.pdf) with some roundrule figures drawn on it.  Now run this program that grabs the two pages from useroundrule.pdf and inserts them as whole-page (captioned) figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{fnum}\newcounter{countindex}

\def\blahblah{, from my other document}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{fnum}{\thefigure}\addtocounter{fnum}{0}% can use as offset
\fboxsep=0pt
\whiledo{\value{countindex} < 2}{
  \stepcounter{countindex}
  \stepcounter{fnum}
  \begin{figure}[p]
  \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.89,trim=48 36 46 60,page=\thefnum]{useroundrule.pdf}}
  \caption{Page \thefnum\blahblah}
  \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Here is an image of the 2nd inserted page:

[image]

IN the above MWE, I scaled and clipped so as to occupy the whole textwidth/textheight.  However, there is no reason one cannot scale and clip to smaller sized images, use `[ht]` figures, rather than `[p]` figures, etc.

This approach was based on part 2 of my answer at [Put entire thesis on one A0 poster?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166418/put-entire-thesis-on-one-a0-poster/166442#166442)

Comment: Thanks! I'll need some time to get back to this and digest your answer...