# Change glyph for quotes

Tags: fonts, punctuation

One should quote with `` and '', for example

```
``quote''
```

will produce

```
"quote"
```

with the correct glyphs, that is the glyphs on the left are a rotation of 180° of the glyphs on the right.

Unfortunately, in some fonts (I am using `mathpazo`) the glyphs for left and right marks are too similar, and they actually look the same, especially when printed with non high quality printers, for example here:

[image]

Is it possible to use a different glyph on the left? I would really like to have something similar to this:

[image]

where it is a lot more clear where the quote starts and ends.

Comment: Are you afraid not to be able to know if you're reading the beginning of the end of the quote? ;_J

Comment: I am afraid that my supervisor will complain again that he is not ;)

Comment: Does he (maybe she?) supervise from left to right of from right to left? ;o)

Comment: If you don't like the design of Palatino (by Hermann Zapf, one of the greatest font designer in the 20th century), use a different font.

Comment: @egreg I love palatino, but my supervisor doesn't like/want these quotes...

Comment: The supervisor's tastes always win over the student's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\def\lQ{\bgroup\fontfamily{cmm}\selectfont``\egroup}
\def\rQ{\bgroup\fontfamily{cmm}\selectfont''\egroup}
\begin{document}
Here is a \lQ test\rQ{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo,graphicx}
\def\lQ{\scalebox{-1}[1]{''}}
\begin{document}
Here is a \lQ test''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Trust the font designer.

Comment: The second is perfect! :D I do trust the font designer, but I have to modify the gliph from the standard because of a request from my supervisor :(

Comment: @dadexix86 You are bringing back nightmares.  I had the same argument with my editor because she did not like the Palatino quotes, which are similar.  So she insisted upon changing the whole document to Times.  Argghh! `8^0`

Comment: Well, fortunately you were here to save my a** from long and fruitless discussions! ;)

Comment: @dadexix86 You might enjoy the intro and part 2 of my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166418/put-entire-thesis-on-one-a0-poster/166442#166442, as to what came of that editorial disagreement.

Comment: Oh gosh, that is so crazy! :S

Comment: The choice of `\lq` as macro name is not really the best.

Comment: @egreg Okay, I changed to `\lQ` and `\rQ`, but for something used as often as a quote, I would hate to make it longer still.

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\reflectbox{''}quote''
```