# Text added on top of \includepdf

Tags: pdfpages

I am trying to include a a PDF file in my latex file, but it turns to background page and all new text and caption lines are written on the same page as my image from PDF.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \begin{centering}
  \includegraphics[width=68mm, height=55mm]{Fotos/figure1}
  \caption{figure1} 
  \label{fig:figure1}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}
some text
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includepdf[pages=-]{fotos/photo.pdf}\label{fig:photo}
\caption{bla bla bla bla}
\end{figure}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but does `\begin{figure}[p]` help?  It should set the figure on its own page with the `[p]` option.

Comment: No, it does not. Also \begin{figure}[ht!] does not help.

Comment: do you mind posting a full MWE? this snippet with a sample PDF does work on my machine.

Comment: @naphaneal I just added a photo how it looks like.

Comment: There is something strange going on there at least, but without a complete example it's probably hard to say what exactly. Does the PDF have only one page? Why are you not using `\includegraphics{fotos/photo}`? (`\includepdf` is not really intended for what you seem to be doing I think.)

Comment: yes, it has only one page. I need to get those data from excel and if I make an image out of it the quality will be really bad and I don't have gnuplot here, so I thought for the sake of quality I insert a PDF instead.

Comment: First try `\includegraphics{fotos/photo}` (or `\includegraphics[width=8cm]{fotos/photo}` if you need to resize it), and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: Thank you so so much. It worked with     \includegraphics{fotos/photo}. :)

Answer (score 4):

`\includepdf` is not intended for that use I think, it is for adding multi-page PDFs, possibly with several pages of the included PDF on one page (e.g. [Put entire thesis on one A0 poster?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166418/put-entire-thesis-on-one-a0-poster/166426#166426) for a silly example).

Just use `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package instead, i.e.

```
\includegraphics{fotos/photo}
```

(the file ending is not necessary). You can also scale it if needed, e.g. `\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{fotos/photo}`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! '\includegraphics' works perfectly.