# In LuaTeX, what is the “identity” linebreak_filter? (Or: how can we use `tex.linebreak` to match the default line-breaking algorithm?)

Tags: line-breaking, luatex, paragraphs

Consider the following LaTeX document (to be compiled with `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\directlua{
  function shouldbenoop(head, isDisplay)
    return tex.linebreak(head)
  end
}
% \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback('linebreak_filter', shouldbenoop, 'This should be same as the default?')}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Whether or not the `add_to_callback` line is commented out, the output appears to be the same, that is our overridden linebreak filter, which calls `tex.linebreak`, appears to do the same thing that TeX does by default.

However, when we try the same with plain TeX (to be compiled with `luatex`):

```
\input ltluatex % For luatexbase.add_to_callback
\input plipsum
\directlua{
  function shouldbenoop(head, isDisplay)
    return tex.linebreak(head)
  end
}
% \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback('linebreak_filter', shouldbenoop, 'This should be same as the default?')}

\lipsum{1-20}
\bye
```

and use the linebreak filter (uncomment the commented line above), the result looks bad, *between* paragraphs:

[image: Paragraphs run together]

The paragraphs appear to overlap almost, and we need to set a higher `\parskip` to get “proper” results (of course they're not proper in the sense that they differ from the result without using the linebreak filter).

The issue is not with loading `ltluatex` in plain, as the result is the same with this:

```
\input plipsum
\directlua{
  function shouldbenoop(head, isDisplay)
    return tex.linebreak(head)
  end
}
\directlua{callback.register('linebreak_filter', shouldbenoop)}

\lipsum{1-20}
\bye
```

It also doesn't have anything to do with `plipsum`, as it is reproducible by simply typing out paragraphs without loading the package.

What is going on? And more importantly, what can we write as a `linebreak_filter` in plain TeX, that will perfectly reproduce the effect of the default line-breaking (that is, be identical to not having a `linebreak_filter`)?

Comment: you get  no space before the following paragraph as `\prevdepth` has the magic "start of list" value of -1000pt instead of the depth of the last line of the previous paragraph, but why it has that isn't so clear....

Comment: in the latex case the output is not _exactly_ identical. The paragraphs are more spaced out when the luatexbase.add_to_callback gets executed.

Comment: with latex `\lipsum[1-54]` will take only 10 pages without the directlua but 11 pages with the last paragraph on page 11 when using the directlua.

Comment: @jfbu I see, thanks. So the effect is opposite in LaTeX, which makes it harder to notice. Probably `prevdepth` gets set to a larger value than the correct one, in LaTeX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reset (at least) `\prevdepth` something like this, otherwise `\prevdepth` gets the "start of list" value of -1000pt and the following paragraph is set with no space before it.

```
\directlua{
  function shouldbenoop(head, isDisplay)
    h,t =tex.linebreak(head)
    tex.prevdepth= t.prevdepth
   return h
  end
}
\directlua{callback.register('linebreak_filter', shouldbenoop)}

\hsize3cm
\parindent0pt

g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g 

\showthe\prevdepth
g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g g


a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a

a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks! How come it works fine in LaTeX?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR not sure (and it's getting late here so I decided to leave that for another day:-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR \prevdepth is 0pt after \begin{document} in LaTeX but -1000pt in plain. If I remember correctly you may have to set other env variables to integrate a paragraph correctly back (I think it is documented somwhere in the luatex manual) tex.linebreak really only does the breaking but not the full integration back into th galley.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Thank you. I think that must be it. I couldn't find anything more about what to do after `tex.linebreak` in the LuaTeX manual, but the TUGboat article [LuaTeX: What it takes to make a paragraph](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100isambert.pdf#page=7) sets `prevdepth` and `prevgraf` after (essentially) calling `tex.linebreak`, so I guess those are the two additional steps needed.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR you have think about tex.linebreak acting like \unvbox  in vertical mode, that also doesn't set anything just appends its material

Answer (score 2):

I am not deleting this for sentimental reasons, but from informed [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403801/in-luatex-what-is-the-identity-linebreak-filter-or-how-can-we-use-tex-lin/403844?noredirect=1#comment1006178_403813) and [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403801/in-luatex-what-is-the-identity-linebreak-filter-or-how-can-we-use-tex-lin/403844?noredirect=1#comment1006254_403813) and from the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403813/4686) by @FrankMittlebach and @DavidCarlisle it is expected that `\prevdepth` (and `\prevgraf`) settings must be restored by the callback. I have not read the manual but it seems from that further [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403801/in-luatex-what-is-the-identity-linebreak-filter-or-how-can-we-use-tex-lin/403844?noredirect=1#comment1006182_403813) by @ShreevatsaR that one needs to gather the information from other sources as well.

---

This is too long but is a comment: in the LaTeX case too, something is broken. Here is my test file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\directlua{
  function shouldbenoop(head, isDisplay)
    return tex.linebreak(head)
  end
}
%\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback('linebreak_filter', shouldbenoop, 'This should be same as the default?')}

\parskip 0pt

\def\x{\rule{2cm}{5pt} }

\def\y{\x\x\x\x}
\def\z{\y\y}

\z

\z g g g 

\z

\thispagestyle{empty}
\showoutput

\end{document}
```

The `g g g` in second paragraph cause the third to move down, when the `\directlua` is executed. The baselineskip glue computed by TeX should be 4.94pt but turns out to be 7pt (making the distance from bottom of `g` to next baseline exactly 7pt+5pt=12pt).

Here is a diff of the logs, cut down to the relevant things. At top of each portion the result with the `\directlua` executed, at bottom, with it commented out. Clearly the last paragraph is positioned lower in former case due to the descenders of letter `g`: TeX's mechanism is broken for maintaining a constant base line.

```
*** 84,90 ****
  ...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, direction TLT
  ..\glue 25.0
  ..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
! ..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 477.88895fil, direction TLT
  ...\write-{}
  ...\glue(\topskip) 5.0
  ...\hbox(5.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set - 1.0, direction TLT
--- 83,89 ----
  ...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, direction TLT
  ..\glue 25.0
  ..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
! ..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 479.94873fil, direction TLT
  ...\write-{}
  ...\glue(\topskip) 5.0
  ...\hbox(5.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set - 1.0, direction TLT
***************
*** 168,174 ****
  ....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
  ....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
  ...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
! ...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.0
  ...\hbox(5.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set - 1.0, direction TLT
  ....\localpar
  .....\localinterlinepenalty=0
--- 167,173 ----
  ....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
  ....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
  ...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
! ...\glue(\baselineskip) 4.94
  ...\hbox(5.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set - 1.0, direction TLT
  ....\localpar
  .....\localinterlinepenalty=0
***************
```

Image of output with `\directlua` executed:

[image]

The last paragraph is moved down.

---

And `\the\prevdepth` indeed produces `0.0pt` in the lua filter case and `2.06pt` without it. (the kind of things one expects as collateral damage from using a `\special`, like happens with using `\color` etc... but here the `\showoutput` does not show such a thing, so must be more in the innards of luatex).

Comment: as I note in my answer you need to set `\prevdepth` in the callback

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as you know I am a no-ob in luatex; so if I get you right, this is documented expected fact that a callback must reset `\prevdepth` ?

Comment: the luatex manual inherits some qualities of the texbook that once you know the answer you can convince yourself that the answer is there,  just not quite where you'd expect:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle abiding by authoritative tradition is indeed important :-)