# Poetry, calligrams and TikZ challenge

Tags: tikz-pgf, poetry

One of my favorite poets is probably Guillaume Apollinaire. His story and proximity to Picasso made him a precursor. [Calligrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calligram) was a constant attempt to merge poetry and visual. I am wondering how we could actually recreate in TikZ [image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: There’s one example of concrete poetry at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193563  I’m not persuaded that `tikz` is the best tool for this.

Comment: A fine challenge! Personally, I'd like to try  *La colombe poignardée et le jet d'eau*, but would prefer to do it with `pstricks`.

Comment: @Bernard oh this one is very pretty too !! I had it to my initial question

Comment: @Thérèse I am not sure I agree: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68740/121799.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403353/48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just to mention that Ti*k*Z has already built in a large selection of tricks that can be applied to paths. Here is a very basic example. (Yes, I know I am not a poet.;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mypath{
 (-2,0) to[bend right=10] (0,5.1)
 to[bend right=10] (2,0) -- (1.5,0) -- (0.8,1) -- (-0.8,1) -- (-1.5,0) -- cycle}
\draw \mypath; 
\path[decorate,decoration={text along path,
text={In Paris there is a tower and beneath it there grows a flower. And often
on Mondays there is a shower.}}] \mypath;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The IMHO most stunning tools are however not from the pgfmanual, but due to [Paul Gaborit's great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68740/121799). You basically define the contour and the macro takes care of the rest. (Of course, you may want to tune things in the end a bit, but it is stunning how much it does out of the box.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,intersections}

\def\shapeparnodeaccuracy{2}
\newcommand\shapeparnode[6][]{
  % 6 parameters:
  % style for node (default:empty),
  % h margin, v margin, left path, right path, text (just one paragraph!)

  % name left and right paths and compute there bounding boxes
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=leftbb]
    \path[name path global=left,xshift=#2] #4;
  \end{scope}
  \node[inner ysep=-#3,inner xsep=0pt,fit=(leftbb)](leftbb){};
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=rightbb]
    \path[name path global=right,xshift=-#2] #5;
  \end{scope}
  \node[inner ysep=-#3,inner xsep=0pt,fit=(rightbb)](rightbb){};

  % global bounding box
  \path let
  \p1=(leftbb.north west), \p2=(leftbb.south west),
  \p3=(rightbb.north east), \p4=(rightbb.south east)
  in
  \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{(\y1 < \y3) ? \y1 : \y3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{(\y2 > \y4) ? \y2 : \y4}
    \typeout{ymin \ymin}
    \typeout{ymax \ymax}
  } node[inner sep=0,fit={(\x1,\ymin pt)(\x3,\ymax pt)}](mybb){};

  % compute nb steps
  \path let \p1=(mybb.north), \p2=(mybb.south) in
  \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\fnthght}{1em/\shapeparnodeaccuracy}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nbsteps}{(\y1-\y2)/\fnthght}
    \xdef\nbsteps{\nbsteps}
    \typeout{nb steps \nbsteps}
  };

  % horizontal references
  \path (mybb.north) -- (mybb.south)
  \foreach \cnt in {0,1,...,\nbsteps}{
    \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\pos}{\cnt/\nbsteps}}
    coordinate[pos=\pos] (ref \cnt)
  };

  % left and right boundaries coordinates
  \foreach \cnt in {0,1,...,\nbsteps}{
    % an horizontal line from left to right
    \path[name path=ltor]
    (mybb.west |- ref \cnt) --  (mybb.east |- ref \cnt);
    % same line from right to left
    \path[name path=rtol]
    (mybb.east |- ref \cnt) -- (mybb.west |- ref \cnt);
    % left boundary
    \path[name intersections={of=rtol and left,by={l \cnt},sort by=rtol}];
    % right boundary
    \path[name intersections={of=ltor and right,by={r \cnt},sort by=ltor}];
  }
  % start point (and initial value of boundshape)
  \path let \p1=(l 0) in 
  \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xstart}{\x1}
    \xdef\boundshape{{0}{0}b{\xstart}}
    \xdef\xmin{\xstart}
    \xdef\xmax{\xstart}
  };

  % top and bottom
  \path let \p1=(l 0), \p2=(l \nbsteps) in
  \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ystart}{\y1}\xdef\ystart{\ystart}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yending}{\y2}\xdef\yending{\yending}
  };
  % incremental definition of boundshape
  \foreach \cnt in {0,1,...,\nbsteps}{
    \path let \p1=(l \cnt), \p2=(r \cnt) in
    \pgfextra{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\start}{\x1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{\x2-\x1}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\ypos}{\cnt/\nbsteps*(\ystart - \yending)}
      {\let\\=\relax \xdef\boundshape{\boundshape\\{\ypos}t{\start}{\len}}}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{(\xmin < \start) ? \xmin : \start}
      \xdef\xmin{\xmin}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{(\xmax > \start + \len) ? \xmax : \start + \len}
      \xdef\xmax{\xmax}
    };
  }
  % draw the node with text in a shapepar
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{\ystart - \yending}
  {\let\\=\relax \xdef\boundshape{\boundshape\\{\ymax}e{0}}}
  \node[#1,text width=\xmax pt - \xmin pt,align=flush left,
  anchor=north west,inner sep=0]
  at (mybb.north west -| \xmin pt,0)
  {\Shapepar[1pt]{\boundshape}#6\par};
}

\def\mytext{In Paris there is a tower and beneath it there grows a flower.}

\begin{document}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\pathone{(0,1) -- (-0.8,1) -- (-1.5,0) --
      (-2,0) to[bend right=10] (0,5.1)}
      \def\pathtwo{(0,5.1)
    to[bend right=10] (2,0) -- (1.5,0) -- (0.8,1) -- (-0.8,1)}
      \fill[top color=lime,bottom color=orange,middle color=yellow,draw=white]
      \pathone -- \pathtwo -- cycle;
      \def\pathone{(0,1) -- (-0.8,1) -- (-1.5,0) --
      (-1.6,0) to[bend right=10] (0,4.1)}
      \def\pathtwo{(0,4.1)
    to[bend right=10] (1.6,0) -- (1.5,0) -- (0.8,1) -- (-0.8,1)}
      \shapeparnode[text=black,font=\footnotesize\scshape]
      {0.1em}{0.1em}{\pathone}{\pathtwo}{\mytext}%
      %\draw[orange] \pathone;
      %\draw[orange] \pathtwo;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Stolen from PSTricks gallery](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery/Gallery):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-text}

\newdimen\MyDim \MyDim=30pt
\makeatletter
\def\doPerChar#1#2\@nil{%
    \CharacterAction{#1}%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\doPerChar#2\@nil\fi}
\def\perChar#1{\doPerChar#1\@nil}
\def\CharacterAction#1{%
  \fontsize{\MyDim}{1.1\MyDim}\selectfont#1%
  \global\advance\MyDim by -0.175pt}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\pstextpath{%
  \parametricplot[linestyle=none,plotpoints=5000,algebraic,unit=0.3]
    {50}{0}[/A 5e-3 def ]{A*(cos(t)+t^2*sin(t)) | A*(sin(t)-t^2*cos(t))}}{\perChar{%
     {$a$}{$\!^2$}+{$b$}{$\!^2$}={$c$}{$\!^2$}~is~from~Pythagoras~%
     who~lived~in~Greek.~{$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$}~is~also~from~him~and~%
     the~same~in~geometry~\ldots}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]