# How can I fit/scale some text to an upper-bound function in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm interested in creating this type of shape for text:

[image]

How can I fit/scale some text to an upper-bound function?

I imagine a newcommand like `\funcText[function]{Text}`, but I am quickly stuck (question of dimension of the text to match the domain of the function + actually scaling the letter according to the function itself).

**Research so far**

This [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482345/163874) where text was fitting into some shapes as in the Calligrams by Guillaume Apollinaire. Based on [this famous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67032/fitting-text-to-a-shape-in-tikz),

[draw-text-in-different-shapes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313880/draw-text-in-different-shapes)

**Examples**

I imagine I could, for instance, apply the method to use a normal curve with text below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    myfonction/.style={
        >={Stealth[length=6pt]},
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        myfonction,
        declare function={
            f(\x)=2*exp(-\x*\x/3);
            xmax=3.5;
            xmin=-3.4;
            x0=1.5;
            ymax=2.75;
        },
    ]

    \draw[thick] plot[domain=xmin:xmax,samples=51,smooth] (\x,{f(\x)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a proof of concept. It may need tweaking. The basic idea is to use the `xstring` package to count the number (`\strlen`) of characters in the text (UTF-8 is ok—see below) and then place and scale each one individually as a node. Horizontal placement is determined (like a Riemann sum) by calculating `(xmax-xmin)/strlen`. Vertical scaling is determined by the function (also like a Riemann sum).

`\functext[red]{2*exp(-\x*\x/3)}{-3.5}{3.5}{HELLOWORLD!}`

[image]

`\functext[blue,font=\sffamily\bfseries]{\x*\x/8+1}{-3.5}{3.5}{TEXT UNDER A PARABOLA!}`

[image]

The general call is

`\functext[<tikz options>]{<function>}{<xmin>}{<xmax>}{<text>}`

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,xstring}

\newcommand{\xfactor}{25}
\newcommand{\yfactor}{3.9}

\newcommand{\functext}[5][]{\StrLen{#5}[\strlen]\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[ultra thin, domain=#3:#4, smooth, variable=\x] plot (\x, {#2});
    \draw[ultra thin] (#3,0)--(#4,0);
    \foreach \n[evaluate=\n as \xt using #3+(#4-#3)/\strlen*(\n-.5),
        evaluate=\n as \x using \xt,
        evaluate={\yt=#2}]
        in {1,...,\strlen}{
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base,yscale=\yt*\yfactor,xscale=\xfactor/\strlen,#1] at (\xt,0) {\StrChar{#5}{\n}}; 
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\functext[red]{2*exp(-\x*\x/3)}{-3.5}{3.5}{HELLOWORLD!}

\vspace{1cm}
\functext[blue,font=\sffamily\bfseries]{\x*\x/8+1}{-3.5}{3.5}{TEXT UNDER A PARABOLA!}

\end{document}
```

The two global constants `\xfactor` and `\yfactor` control the width and height of the letters. Larger `\xfactor` makes the letters wider (overlapping if too large). Larger `\yfactor` makes the letters taller relative to the function (crossing it if too large). If you want space between the letters and the function, decrease this value. Font changes may require adjustment of these factors.

You can delete the first two `\draw` commands in the macro if you don't want the curve (and x-axis) drawn.

Lowercase letters are fine but they won't reach the function (except f, d, etc.). UTF-8 characters require `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble, and accented uppercase letters will likely extend above the function unless you reduce `\yfactor`.

The same technique works to draw text between two curves. We define a new macro `\funcstext` that takes 6 arguments (one optional):

`\funcstext[<tikz options>]{<function1>}{<function2>}{<xmin>}{<xmax>}{<text>}`

`\funcstext[green!50!black,font=\sffamily\bfseries]{2*exp(-\x*\x/3)}{-\x*\x/8}{-3.5}{3.5}{TEXT BETWEEN TWO CURVES!}`

[image]

Here is the code for the macro:

```
\newcommand{\funcstext}[6][]{\StrLen{#6}[\strlen]\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[ultra thin, domain=#4:#5, smooth, variable=\x] plot (\x, {#2});
    \draw[ultra thin, domain=#4:#5, smooth, variable=\x] plot (\x, {#3});
    \foreach \n[evaluate=\n as \xt using #4+(#5-#4)/\strlen*(\n-.5),
        evaluate=\n as \x using \xt,
        evaluate={\yt=#2-#3},
        evaluate={\yb=#3}]
        in {1,...,\strlen}{
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base,yscale=\yt*\yfactor,xscale=\xfactor/\strlen,#1] at (\xt,\yb) {\StrChar{#6}{\n}}; 
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}}
```

This works even if the functions intersect, with possibly desirable consequences:

`\funcstext[orange,font=\sffamily\bfseries]{2*exp(-\x*\x/3)}{\x*\x/8}{-3.5}{3.5}{CAN I DRAW TEXT ON A MöBIUS STRIP?}`

[image]

Comment: Wow! Very nice implementation, Sandy! +1

Comment: Very nice indeed !

Comment: @SebGlav I follow you and know you're a pgfkey expert. May I ask you how you would turn the 6-parameter macro into a probably smoother key command ? That would be a great second answer.

Comment: @JeT Thanks for your kind words, but I'm no expert at all ;) You could ask this as a new question, and receive answers from many great helpers.