# Help creating a 3x3 column layout for game instruction sheets

Tags: multicolumn

I would like to have a standardized way of having the instructions of some card board
games that I have.

Optimally I would like to have them on a piece of paper that is folded to the size,
roughly, of the playing cards and stored alongside the pack of cards.

I figured that if I fold a page in threes, length wise and width wise the end result is
very close to what I want.

So basically I am looking for a latex template that will allow me to layout my text as
in the following rough sketch I did:

[image]

(The red outline is the actual physical size of the page)

- I would like the actual printable page size to be defined (both in height and width)

  - In order to accommodate both A4 and letter sized pages I would like to explicitly define the height and width, and the template to take care of the centering
- I would like an actual printable border so I can cut the final sheet (marked black in my example)
- The flow of text is from from box 1 to 2 to 3, 4, 5 etc

Nice to haves:

It would be interesting if there were some template params that could be easily tweaked
so if the whole instruction sheets ended up being 2.25 pages, that they could be tweak
and make them fit in 2 pages only.

For example:

- Distance between columns
- text font size
- line height
- etc

Also these params could be tweaked to manually increase a page size of 2.85 to 3 pages.

If this 3x3 layout is not trivial, how about a simple 3 column layout that fullfills
the same requirements?

Is there someone proficient enough to help out here, as my latex-foo is not strong
enough....?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You could try https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram in case no other good solutions are offered here. An example is given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529354/position-of-a-headline-in-a-multicolumn-poster-using-flow-window-frame

Comment: Did you look at https://ctan.org/pkg/leaflet ?