# Rescale paragraph to fit margins or detect used width of paragraph

Tags: boxes, paragraphs, scaling, width

I want to write a command or similar that allows me to rescale a given paragraph to fit a given frame, keeping the aspect ratio. The problem is that the paragraph is usually manually set and not automatically wrapped (and thus I do not know its width).

To give an example, using the `adjustbox` package, I can combine `minsizebox` and `maxsizebox` to define `almostwhatiwant` in the following way (the boxes generated with `displayconstraint` are just for illustration):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\displayconstraint}[1]{\fbox{\begin{minipage}[l][3cm]{5cm} #1 \end{minipage}}}
\newcommand{\almostwhatiwant}[1]{\maxsizebox{5cm}{3cm}{\minsizebox{5cm}{3cm}{#1}}}
\begin{document}\noindent
    \displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{test}} % example 1
    \displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{t}}\\ % example 2
    \displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{test\\test test}} % example 3
    \displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{\parbox{\linewidth}{test\\test test}}} % example 4
\end{document}
```

renders the following:

[image]

The first two examples (top row) are rendered as desired, but as soon as I want to make linebreaks, I encounter the problem that I have to use a paragraph-like environment (otherwise, the third example happens), for which I have to specify a linewidth. This allows me to format the text in the way I want, but its width as used by the rescaling boxes is now the specified linewidth and thus the result is dissatisfactory (example 4).

I am aware of many other approaches to this problem, but they all eventually fail due to similar reasons or require me to do something manually (like detecting the longest line of the paragraph).

I could fix this problem, if I could somehow detect the actual width of a paragraph or crop a paragraph to its actual content.

Comment: If you are manually linebrealing use `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}zzz\\zzz\end{tabular}` to make a box as wide as the longest line

Comment: Somewhat related (if you need autowrap): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/making-the-text-fit-in-a-specific-space-in-latex

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: But that solution only works, if the text is long enough to be autwrapped to a certain height and if I am not mistaken, it cannot be easily tweaked to do what I want, right?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft  That is a good point.  I had not realized the limitation of needing a line long enough to wrap to begin with.  I'll think some more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `tabular` or `varwidth`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,varwidth}
\newcommand{\displayconstraint}[1]{\fbox{\begin{minipage}[l][3cm]{5cm} #1 \end{minipage}}}
\newcommand{\almostwhatiwant}[1]{\maxsizebox{5cm}{3cm}{\minsizebox{5cm}{3cm}{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\raggedright
    \displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{test}} % example 1
    \displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{t}}\\ % example 2
    \displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{test\\test test}} % example 3
    \displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}test\\test test\end{tabular}}} % example 4


\displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
test test
\end{varwidth}}}
\displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
test test test test
\end{varwidth}}}
\displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
test test test test test test
\end{varwidth}}}
\displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
test test test test test test test test
\end{varwidth}}}
\displayconstraint{\almostwhatiwant{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
test test test test test test test test test test
\end{varwidth}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Using tabulars is definetely a huge step forward, in particular since I can move `\begin{tabular}` and `end{tabular}` into the definition of `\almostwhatiwant`. Unfortunately, this solution cannot cope with the text exceeding some predefined width and being autowrapped in some cases – so I would need two variants of `\almostwhatiwant`, one for short-lined and one for long-lined, autowrapped texts.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft  you could use the `varwidth` package to give you an environment with a max witth I'll add an example

Comment: @Wrzlprmft updated with `varwidth` version

Comment: Wonderful. Indeed, there is no need for tabular anymore.