# Fitting text of unknown length into a box through font scaling

Tags: luatex, fontsize

In a scenario where TeX documents are generated by a script the challenge is to nicely fit text of variable length into boxes of fixed size.

There's a default font size suited for 80% of the cases but if a box would become overfull, the TeX engine* should reduce the font size of that box until the text fits in the box.

Is this possible?

(Sorry for not providing sample code by I think it's clear from the explanation.)

If this is a scenario where LuaTeX works well, I'm happy to look into it.

Comment: This is possible. You needn't Lua prefix before TeX. The solution with classical TeX can be found at http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#scaleto

Comment: This seems to be for a given width only, not a multi-line paragraph with many words.

Comment: You _should_ supply a sample code though, why make anyone considering an answer make their own test file?

Comment: do you mean limit the _vertical_ size to avoid overfull vboxes?

Comment: Scale nothing if box not full. Reduce font size if necessary to fit text in a fixed box.

Comment: and with box I really mean a fixed rectangle on the page

Comment: Your question is still massively unclear and you should supply an example. Normally boxes grow vertically to exactly contain the supplied text, so they are never overfull. It is possible to specify a box with fixed vertical extent but how exactly are you doing that?

Comment: Perhaps this?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/making-the-text-fit-in-a-specific-space-in-latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet again `tcolorbox` answer. First with a macro version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fitting]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newtcboxfit{\mybox}[3][]{colback=red!25!olive,
colframe=red!75!olive,fonttitle=\bfseries,
boxsep=1mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,
bottom=0mm,center upper,valign=center,
nobeforeafter,#1,width=#2,height=#3}

\begin{document}
%% \mybox[<optional>]{<width>}{<height>}{<content>}
\mybox{5cm}{3cm}{\lipsum[1]}
\mybox[colback=green!30]{6cm}{4cm}{\lipsum[1]}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Now the environment form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fitting,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newtcolorbox{fitbox}[3][]{fit,,width=#2,height=#3,boxsep=1pt,valign=center,opacityupper=0.5,
top=0.4\tcbfitdim,bottom=0.4\tcbfitdim,left=0.75\tcbfitdim,right=0.75\tcbfitdim,
enhanced,watermark text={\tcbfitsteps},colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white,#1}

\begin{document}
%\begin{fitbox}[<optional>]{<width>}{<height>}
  %contents
%\end{fitbox}
\begin{fitbox}{4cm}{2cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{fitbox}
\begin{fitbox}[colback=green!20]{2cm}{4cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{fitbox}
\begin{fitbox}{1cm}{2cm}
\lipsum[3]
\end{fitbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]