# Enlarge the text area to an appropriate size to fit in the paper size

Tags: paper-size, size

Is there a package to automatically enlarge the text area to fit the paper size? Note that the purpose is NOT to put more texts in one page; the purpose is that, with the same amount of texts in one page, the text area should make better use of spaces by making texts larger.

Comment: Would you consider this answer relevant?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/making-the-text-fit-in-a-specific-space-in-latex/123650#123650

Comment: did the comment of Steven B. Segletes help you?