# Shrink student's book page to add comment to teacher in textbook

Tags: geometry, comments, todonotes, teaching

we are writing a school textbook and the corresponding teacher's book.

The student's book template is good already, so let me explain what I would like to have for the teacher's book.

Each page of the teacher's book should show an exact copy of the corresponding page from the student's book, shrunk and translated to the corner of the page. In the remaining page area, we would like to add a conversation with the teacher.

The two choices we have considered have their issues:

The first choice would be to increase the margins and use`\usepackage{todonotes}` to add the conversation with the teacher.
This guarantees that the comments to the teacher will stay close to the corresponding issues to be addressed.

However there are some problems with this solution:

1. the student's page could render differently from the original (for example the pagebreaks could happen in different places).
2. Also seems quite challenge to do this with `\usepackage{geometry}` and I don't know if it will be possible to write on the top (or bottom) margins with the `todonotes` package.
3. It seems that more elaborate things (like an `enumerate` environment) do not work within the `\todo`.

The second solution we have thought is to compile the student's book separately and only then include each page using

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdf[pages={1}]{myfile.pdf}
```

Now the student's minipages would render correctly, but the problem in this case is that the conversation with the teacher could end up far away from the corresponding activity.

I'm searching for a solution.

It is quite different from [Making the text fit in a specific space in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/making-the-text-fit-in-a-specific-space-in-latex) since we need the student page to be the same in the teacher's book.

Comment: You could hyperlink the conversation to a separate page, opening up a new window.