# How to resize font into box automatically?

Tags: fontsize, resize

I need to fit the size of the text automatically within a box with predefined sizes.
I have a minimum font size for little text and I want to reduce the size for large texts, as can be seen in the figure below.

**P.S. I do not know how many words the text will have.**

[image]

Comment: (1) Resizing text like this is officially evil. (2) What have you tried? (3) I can't see your picture, only 'enter image description here'.

Comment: Of course, you mean that you have a *maximum* font size for *short* text and you want to reduce the size for longer texts.  I see essentially only one way, using a loop: typeset the text in a temporary parbox, measure its height, if it is too high then reduce the font size and start over, otherwise you are done, place the box (or “unvbox” it) where it is meant to go.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=text+fit+box+

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/making-the-text-fit-in-a-specific-space-in-latex